# Aligning the right parts in multiple \begin{cases}

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, braces, cases

Is there an intelligent way to left-align the parts right of & of the two cases environments shown below (if x >= 0, otherwise, if y < 0, otherwise). I wonder if there is a better way than using manual spaces:

```
\begin{align*}
 u(x) &=
  \begin{cases}
   0        & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\
   1        & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  \\
 \tau &=
  \begin{cases}
   a+b+c+d  & \text{if } y < 0 \\
   1        & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: The easiest solution I can come up with is to use the `mathtools` package and use something like `\mathrlap0\hphantom{a+b+c+d}` in place of your 0. But that's playing with manual spacing, I suppose.

Comment: You can use the solutions to [an earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/aligning-across-aligned-equation-blocks), just exchanging the order of the statements.

Comment: Both great. Thanks. Much better than fiddling with manual \quad-s etc.

Comment: @TH, @Caramdir: Why not post actual answers?

Comment: @TH, @Caramdir: If you can put up an answer or two, as @SamB suggests, then we can shift this qn off the "Unanswered" list.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the solutions to an [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/aligning-across-aligned-equation-blocks), just exchanging the order of the statements.

Another solution is to use the `mathtools` package and use something like `\mathrlap0\hphantom{a+b+c+d}` in place of your 0.