# How can I align multiple cases environment simultaneously?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cases

In one big align environment, I want to put some cases environments. I would like the alignment of the cases environments to be the same. For example, if I write:

```
\begin{align}
f(x) &= 
  \begin{cases}
    x & \text{if } x\geq 0,\\
    -x & \text{if } x <0,
  \end{cases}\\
g(x) &=
  \begin{cases}
    \sqrt{x} & \text{if } x \geq 0,\\
    -\sqrt{-x} & \text{if } x < 0.
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
```

then the equation looks ugly because the two cases environment are aligned at different points. Is there a way to force the alignment point of the two environment to be the same?

Comment: See also [Aligning the right parts in multiple \begin{cases}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3338) (possible duplicate), but here you have the better answers.

Comment: I searched for it, but I did not find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You could also use a `\hphantom{}` to add the appropriate amount of horizontal space:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(x) &= 
  \begin{cases}
    x\hphantom{-\sqrt{-}} & \text{if } x\geq 0,\\
    -x & \text{if } x <0,
  \end{cases}\\
g(x) &=
  \begin{cases}
    \sqrt{x} & \text{if } x \geq 0,\\
    -\sqrt{-x} & \text{if } x < 0.
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was hoping in something that does not require some sort of manual spacing, that I could also use in more complicated examples. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 11):

You can enclose one of the entries in  the first `cases`  environment in a box whose width is that of the longest of the second `cases` environment.

```
\newlength{\temp}
\settowidth{\temp}{$-\sqrt{-x}$}
\begin{align}
f(x) &= 
  \begin{cases}
    \makebox[\temp][l]{$x$} & \text{if } x\geq 0,\\
    -x & \text{if } x <0,
  \end{cases}\\
g(x) &=
  \begin{cases}
    \sqrt{x} & \text{if } x \geq 0,\\
    -\sqrt{-x} & \text{if } x < 0.
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of `hphantom` and `mathrlap` provided by the package `mathtools`. Put the longest expression in `hphantom` and wrap `mathrlap` around the expression that `hphantom` is placed after.

In your example, the longest expression is `-\sqrt{-x}`. To place `hphantom` where `x` is, use

```
\mathrlap{x}\hphantom{-\sqrt{-x}}
```

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  f(x) &= \begin{cases}
    \mathrlap{x}\hphantom{-\sqrt{-x}} & \text{if } x\geq 0,\\
    -x & \text{if } x <0,
  \end{cases}\\
  g(x) &= \begin{cases}
    \sqrt{x} & \text{if } x \geq 0,\\
    -\sqrt{-x} & \text{if } x < 0.
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001), not code snippets.