# How can I align similar equations with different variables?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

For example:

```
\begin{align}
    \begin{cases}
        & x = X/Z = 1\\
        & y = Y/Z = 1\\
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
```

Any way to have the spacing for the X and Y be the same so that the other variables/digits align?

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, you are using the `cases` environment to place a french brace on the left side of your expressions.

Assuming that this is all you are using `cases` for, you can use regular delimiters instead of `cases`, which gives you greater flexibility with alignment environments.

As in [Stefan Kottwitz's second answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41422/aligning-conditions-in-cases-environment), you can just use the `\left{` and `\right.` delimiters to achieve the same result as `cases` in your example above.

Also from that answer, you can use the `alignedat` environment to control the alignment of your expressions.

This code aligns the expressions about both `=` signs:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \left\{% open left french brace delimiter
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    x &= X/Z &= 1 \\
    y &= Y/Z &= 1 \\
  \end{alignedat}
  \right.% close the delimiter
\]
\end{document}
```

However, this code does *not* have equation numbers as you would find with `align`.

If the equation numbers are necessary for your project, you could use `\hphantom{}` as discussed in [Peter Grill's answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96568/how-can-i-align-multiple-cases-environment-simultaneously) within an `align` environment to preserve the equation numbers, though this would be a much more fiddly process than using `alignedat` with delimiters as discussed above.

Comment: +1 for the term "french brace" for `{` and `}`. So far, I've only seen them called "curly braces".

Answer (score 2):

You could insert an `array` environment inside the `cases` environment to create extremely flexible formatting options. (In the code below, the `@{{}={}}` particles generate appropriately-spaced `=` symbols.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \begin{cases}
        \begin{array}{l @{{}={}} l @{{}={}} l}
            x & X/Y/Z & 1\\
            abc & M/L & uvw
        \end{array}
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

*Remark*: For the example at hand, neither the `align` environment nor the `cases` environment is needed. A simpler (and more compactly formatted) solution would be:

```
\begin{equation}
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{l @{{}={}} l @{{}={}} l}
           x & X/Y/Z & 1\\
           abc & M/L & uvw
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a mixture of [`empheq`](http://ctan.org/pkg/empheq) and some box manipulation. Here are three different options, depending on what kind of equation numbering you're after (more options exist):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq} % Loads mathtools and amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
  x &= X/Y/Z = 1 \\
  y &= \mathrlap{Y/Z}\phantom{X/Y/Z} = 1
\end{empheq}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    &\hspace*{-1em} x = X/Y/Z = 1 \\
    &\hspace*{-1em} \mathrlap{y}\phantom{x} = \mathrlap{Y/Z}\phantom{X/Y/Z} = 1
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\[
  \begin{cases}
    &\hspace*{-1em} x = X/Y/Z = 1 \\
    &\hspace*{-1em} \mathrlap{y}\phantom{x} = \mathrlap{Y/Z}\phantom{X/Y/Z} = 1
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

`\mathrlap` is provided by [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) which is loaded automatically by `empheq`.

Some minor left-brace size differences are noticeable, but it would mostly be negligible to the inconspicuous reader.