# Aligning multiple equations (which involve cases) at multiple places

Tags: math-mode, cases, alignat

I am trying to align this set of equations at two places. Essentially, I want all the equals/`neq` signs to be aligned.

[image]

I am aware of the `alignat` environment which allows you to align an equation at multiple points. However, this doesn't seem to work as I have `\begin{cases}` within my equation (`cases` requires a `\\` which appears to be confusing `alignat`?)

### When I try use `\begin{alignat}{2}`

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\bm{\tilde{A}}^{(n)\intercal} \mathbf{M} \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(m)} 
            =\begin{cases}
               0, \quad n \neq m\\
               1, \quad n = m
            \end{cases}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\bm{\tilde{A}}^{(n)\intercal} \mathbf{K} \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(m)}                                  
            =\begin{cases}
               0, \quad n \neq m\\
               \omega_n^2, \quad n = m.
            \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\bm{\tilde{A}}^{(n)\intercal} \mathbf{M} \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(m)} 
            &=\begin{cases}
               0, \quad n &&\neq m\\
               1, \quad n &&= m
            \end{cases}
\shortintertext{and}
\bm{\tilde{A}}^{(n)\intercal} \mathbf{K} \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(m)}                                  
            &=\begin{cases}
               0, \quad n &&\neq m\\
               \omega_n^2, \quad n &&= m.
            \end{cases}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use a combination of `align` and `makebox` as shown here:  [How can I align multiple cases environment simultaneously?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96569/134144)

Comment: You are usign `cases` wrong, it is normally a two column construction, each column separated by `&`, so remove the `\quad` and write ``0, & n \new m \\`` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\shortintertext` is OK, but in order to align the conditions, you need some more work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\bm{\tilde{A}}^{(n)\intercal} \mathbf{M} \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(m)} 
&=\begin{cases}
  \mathmakebox[\widthof{$\omega_n^2,$}][l]{0,} & n \neq m,\\
  \mathmakebox[\widthof{$\omega_n^2,$}][l]{1,} & n = m,
\end{cases}
\\
\shortintertext{and}
\bm{\tilde{A}}^{(n)\intercal} \mathbf{K} \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(m)}                                  
&=\begin{cases}
  \mathmakebox[\widthof{$\omega_n^2,$}][l]{0,} & n \neq m,\\
  \omega_n^2, & n = m.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation with `eqparbox`: the defined command `\matheqbox` takes two arguments, the first is an arbitrary label for the internal workings. Different alignments need different labels.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\matheqbox}[3][\displaystyle]{%
  \eqmakebox[#2][l]{$#1#3$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\bm{\tilde{A}}^{(n)\intercal} \mathbf{M} \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(m)} 
&=\begin{cases}
  \matheqbox{A}{0,} & n \neq m,\\
  \matheqbox{A}{1,} & n = m,
\end{cases}
\\
\shortintertext{and}
\bm{\tilde{A}}^{(n)\intercal} \mathbf{K} \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(m)}                                  
&=\begin{cases}
  \matheqbox{A}{0,} & n \neq m,\\
  \matheqbox{A}{\omega_n^2}, & n = m.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: isn't it easier with `eqparbox` and why isn't there a mathaware version of `eqparbox`?

Comment: @daleif I was just writing it

Comment: I was faster  ;-), I thought I'd seen a math aware version of `eqparbox` but probably remembered wrong, would be nice to have a version where we don't need the `$...$`

Comment: The `\matheqbox` probably ought to be made with `xparse` such that one could also access the second optional arg of `\eqmakebox`, but that is just details.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `eqparbox` and `align`

The good thing with `eqparbox` is that it keeps track of the widest entry automatically at the cost of having to compile a few times. The W is the unique name for this box set.

Just remember that the contents inside `\eqparbox` is text, so we need the `$...$`.

Or use egregs `\matheqbox` addition in his answer

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\bm{\tilde{A}}^{(n)\intercal} \mathbf{M} \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(m)} 
            &=\begin{cases}
               \eqmakebox[W][l]{$0$,} & n \neq m\\
               \eqmakebox[W][l]{$1$,} & n = m
             \end{cases}
             \\
\intertext{and}
            \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(n)\intercal} \mathbf{K} \bm{\tilde{A}}^{(m)}                                  
            &=\begin{cases}
              \eqmakebox[W][l]{$0$,} & n \neq m\\
              \eqmakebox[W][l]{$\omega_n^2$,}& n = m.
            \end{cases}
\end{align}


 \end{document}
```

[image]