# Mixed Grouping in Subequations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

I am looking to create a subequation environment with three equations. However, I want to group the 2nd and 3rd equations with a brace on the left side. I tried this (using the empheq package):

```
\begin{subequations}
 \begin{align}
   A&=B \\
 \end{align}
 \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
   C&=D \\
   E&=F
 \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
```

But the alignment (as expected) between the two sets of equations doesn't come out well. Any hints?

Comment: I'm sure the following should be of help: [Aligning across `aligned` equation blocks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1938/5764); give some feedback on your findings.

Comment: @Werner Thanks! That tip works great. Everything lines up automatically now (I had resigned myself to a bit of whitespace voodoo to get it done the other day).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are willing to do some manual shifting:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\leftstuff}[2][0pt]{\smash{\raisebox{#1}{\llap{#2}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
 \begin{align}
   A&=B \\
\leftstuff[-0.65em]{\Bigg\{\;}
   C&=D \\
   E&=F
 \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the optional argument you shift the brace up or down, and I've manually specified the brace size (`\Bigg`) and the spacing (`\;`).