# Align inside align

Tags: amsmath, align, braces, nesting

I have a list of equations with annotations like the one below:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  aaaa &= 1  &&\text{for $X$} \\
  bbbb &= 1  &&\text{for $Y$} \\
  c    &= 1  &&\text{for $Z$} \\
  d    &= 12 &&\text{for $Z$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Since the last two lines have the same annotation, I'd like to add a brace there and put the annotation next to the brace. I know that I can do that like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \left. \begin{aligned}
    c &= 1 \\
    d &= 12 \\
  \end{aligned} \right\} &&\text{for $Z$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But how to join the two? The last two lines will only be aligned among themselves, not with the first two. Is there a way out of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1938/2417) help?

Comment: @IanThompson: I'm not sure. The problem seems related but one solution uses an array environment (which does not allow me to number lines) and the doesn't address the problem afaict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a naive attempt at positioning braces in `align`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  aaaa &= 1  &&\text{for $X$} \\
  bbbb &= 1  &&\text{for $Y$} \\
  c    &= 1  && \\
  d    &= 12 &&\llap{\smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\normalbaselineskip+.5\jot}{$\left.\begin{array}{c}\null\\[\jot]\null\end{array}\right\}\quad$}}}
      \text{\smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\normalbaselineskip+.5\jot}{for $Z$}}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The combination of `\smash` (removing any vertical height), `\raisebox` (for vertical movement) and `\llap` (removing horizontal width using a `l`eft over`lap`) allows for manipulating the position of the brace.

Of course, the (horizontal) location of the brace can be adjusted.

Comment: So `\smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\normalbaselineskip+.5\jot}{<content>}}` is an idiom for positioning something centered between two lines. On top of that, `\left.\begin{array}{c}\null\\[\jot]\null\end{array}\right\}` creates a brace of the right height through an empty array of the right height, if I understand correctly. Is there no easier way to create some kind of phantom of the right height? The array seems a bit scary in there :)

Comment: (Sorry, I have to ask): If I replace the `align*` environment with an `align` environment, the last line will now get two numbers. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @anonymous: There are *other* ways of doing this; not sure whether they would be considered *easier* though. You can use `\nonumber` on every line where you want to suppress the equation number. However, using your setup, this will not work since the number will be aligned with the equations, not the "descriptors" (the "for ..." part). Then you need to consider something else, which might require a different solution. Perhaps consider asking a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/5764).

Comment: I've now asked the follow-up question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68547/alignment-across-nested-aligned-environments

Comment: Can an align environment be nested inside another align environment?

Comment: @Royi: Have you tried it? There are ways around multiple alignments that doesn't require a nested `align`.

Comment: But just to know, is it OK to use 'align' inside 'align'?

Comment: @Royi: It's okay, but it doesn't work. ;) As I said before, if you're interested in multiple alignments, there are other options that doesn't require nesting.