# Curly Bracket over multiple equation

Tags: equations, brackets

I have a question regarding the curvy brackets in tex. Didn't find a good solution for the problem yet:

I have the following formulas:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    f(x) &= x + 1 \\
    g(x) &= x + 2 \\
    h(x) &= x + 3 \\
    k(x) &= x + 4 \\
    l(x) &= x + 5 
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Now I want to have a curly bracket around f(x) and g(x) on the right side and want to write some stuff behind the curly bracket. And I also want a curly bracket behind h(x), k(x) and l(x). How can I manage that and also make sure, that all five equations are aligned on the "="-sign?

I just tried to put the formulas in a \begin{rcases} ... \end{rcases}, but then the formulas are no longer aligned.

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards!

Comment: Do you really want a single number for the equation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `nicematrix` and its powerful methods.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\AtBeginEnvironment{NiceArray}{\tracinglostchars=0 }

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceArray}{ @{} r @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} l l}
  f(x) &=& x + 1 & \Block{2-1}{\text{whatever}}\\
  g(x) &=& x + 2 \\
  h(x) &=& x + 3 & \Block{3-1}{\text{something else}}\\
  k(x) &=& x + 4 \\
  l(x) &=& x + 5 \\
\CodeAfter
\SubMatrix.{1-3}{2-3}\}
\SubMatrix.{3-3}{5-3}\}
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

The strange setting to `\tracinglostchars` is to avoid spurious warnings (but they deserve some investigation).

The specifications for the columns are the usual ones to mimic `aligned`, including the setting to `\arraystretch`. We build two “submatrices”, with empty delimiter on the left and braces on the right, plus two blocks spanning two and three rows respectively.

[image]

A couple of LaTeX runs are necessary for the output to stabilize, because ornamentations are set in successive steps after the object has been measured.

Comment: Just a curiosità. Is It possibile to create two same curly brackets?

Comment: @Sebastiano No, if you mean with the same thickness; maybe with other fonts.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

One neat way is to define a new column type for the alignment at `=` as follows

```
\newcolumntype{e}{@{{$\mspace{\thinmuskip}$}}c@{{}}}
```

`NiceArray` from `nicematrix` works well for such for such purpose

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcolumntype{e}{@{{$\mspace{\thinmuskip}$}}c@{{}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \everymath{\displaystyle}
    \begin{NiceArray}[cell-space-limits=3.7pt]{r e @{\quad}l}
        f(x) &= x + 1 & \Block[l]{2-1}{\text{Text for $f(x)$} \\ \text{and $g(x)$}}
    \\
        g(x) &= x + 2 &
    \\
        h(x) &= x + 3 & \Block[l]{3-1}{\text{Text for $h(x)$,} \\ \text{$k(x)$, and $k(x)$}}
    \\
        k(x) &= x + 4 &
    \\
        l(x) &= x + 5 &
    \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{2-2}{\}}[extra-height=-1.1pt]
    \SubMatrix{.}{3-2}{5-2}{\}}[extra-height=-1.1pt]
    \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood correctly your question. For my understanding, the following should do the trick

```
\documentclass{article}
   
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\left.\begin{aligned}
    f(x) &= x + 1 \\
    g(x) &= x + 2 \\
\end{aligned}\right\}\hspace{0.5cm}\text{some stuff}\\
&\left.\begin{aligned}
    h(x) &= x + 3 \\
    k(x) &= x + 4 \\
    l(x) &= x + 5 
\end{aligned}\right\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

If the RHS of all the equation has the same length, the inner alignments & will luckily produce the desired alignment. However, if you really want to force the alignment the solution is less straightforward and I suggest you to have a look at the following question: [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68547/alignment-across-nested-aligned-environments)