# How can I align two split environments at the equal signs?

Tags: math-mode, align

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,  amsthm,  amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \begin{split}
            \label{eq:lines}
            Q_{1x} &= C_{1x} + \mu_1 \vec{h_{1x}} \\
            Q_{1y} &= C_{1y} + \mu_1 \vec{h_{1y}} \\
            \vdots \\
            Q_{3z} &= C_{3z} + \mu_3 \vec{h_{3z}}
        \end{split} \\
        \begin{split}
            \label{eq:distances}
            \overline{Q_1 Q_2}^2 &= (Q_{1x}-Q_{2x})^2 + (Q_{1y}-Q_{2y})^2 + (Q_{1z}-Q_{2z})^2\\
            \vdots
        \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

I want to align the equations in both split-environments along the "="-Symbol in the same way. 
Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: added such an example

Comment: The solution to [Aligning across 'aligned' equation blocks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1946/15925) should be adaptable to this situation.  Of course, it may be simpler to make your example one `align` and just use `\notag` on the lines that should not be numbered.

Comment: @Andrew: but then the eqn number is not centered around the group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is to remember to put alignment signs `&` on all the lines in your `splits` (your code has none on the `\vdots` lines).  Minimising your example gives:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   \label{eq:lines}
   \begin{split}       
      Q_{1x} &= C_{1x} + \mu_1 \vec{h_{1x}} \\
      Q_{1y} &= C_{1y} + \mu_1 \vec{h_{1y}} \\
      \vdots& \\
      Q_{3z} &= C_{3z} + \mu_3 \vec{h_{3z}}
   \end{split} \\
   \label{eq:distances}
   \begin{split}        
      \overline{Q_1 Q_2}^2 &= (Q_{1x}-Q_{2x})^2 + (Q_{1y}-Q_{2y})^2 
                                      + (Q_{1z}-Q_{2z})^2\\
      \vdots&
   \end{split}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Now you need to decide how you want to place the `\vdots`...

### Discussion

The documentation `amsmath.pdf` is not so clear about this structure saying

> The split structure should constitute the entire body of the enclosing structure, 
>   apart from commands like \label that produce no visible material.

in the section "Split equations with alignment", in contrast to the description under `gather`

> Any equation in a gather may consist of a \begin{split} ... \end{split} structure—...

However, the accompanying filed `testmath.pdf` contains two explicit examples of multiple `splits` within an `align`.  What you can't do is enclose such a `split` construction inside e.g. a `\left ... \right` construction.

Note that there is the package `breqn` which contains code that allows complicated alignment between various blocks, but it alters fundamental constructions in math mode, and so has a number of compatibility issues.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I have to admit, I have no idea why this worked, just wanted to add an example using the `\vdotswithin{}` from `mathtools` and all of a sudden the `=`'s aligned. I also changed the `\vec` to only go over the `h`'s.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,  amsthm,  amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \begin{split}
            \label{eq:lines}
            Q_{1x} &= C_{1x} + \mu_1 \vec{h}_{1x} \\
            Q_{1y} &= C_{1y} + \mu_1 \vec{h}_{1y} \\
            &\vdotswithin{=} \\
            Q_{3z} &= C_{3z} + \mu_3 \vec{h}_{3z}
        \end{split} \\
        \begin{split}
            \label{eq:distances}
            \overline{Q_1 Q_2}^2 
            &= (Q_{1x}-Q_{2x})^2 + (Q_{1y}-Q_{2y})^2 + (Q_{1z}-Q_{2z})^2\\
            &\vdotswithin{=}
          \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It turns out that it has nothing to do with `\vdotswithin`.  See my answer!

Answer (score 5):

You need `aligned` instead of `split`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\templen}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\templen}{$\displaystyle\overline{Q_1 Q_2}^2$}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:lines}
&\begin{aligned}
\makebox[\templen][r]{$\displaystyle Q_{1x}$} &= C_{1x} + \mu_1 \vec{h_{1x}} \\
Q_{1y} &= C_{1y} + \mu_1 \vec{h_{1y}} \\
\vdots \\
Q_{3z} &= C_{3z} + \mu_3 \vec{h_{3z}}
\end{aligned} \\
\label{eq:distances}
&\begin{aligned}
\overline{Q_1 Q_2}^2 &= (Q_{1x}-Q_{2x})^2 + (Q_{1y}-Q_{2y})^2 + (Q_{1z}-Q_{2z})^2\\
\vdots
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The `\templen` width can be reused at will. It must be set outside the `align` environment.