# Aligning multiple sets of equations equally with one case per set

Tags: equations, align, multirow

Using LaTeX, how could I achieve the below:

[image]

Note how the left equations are aligned around the `=` which can be achieved using `align*`. The right case with the center text can likewise be achieved using some clever placement of `\left.` and `\right}`, however the equation sets on the left are aligned to eachother, meaning they'd have to be in one `align*` environment rather than one per set.

I figure I'm looking for something like a multirow for the `align*` or `array` environments.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1946/89497) might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a solution with `multirow` package, `\mybrace` is defined to create right brace which occupy two rows.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\mybrace}{$\left.\vphantom{\begin{array}{c}
 x  \\
 y     
\end{array}}\right\rbrace$}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{rclcl}

3x+4y      &=&-2    &\multirow{2}{*}{\mybrace}& \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{4cm}
{\raggedright text text text text text text text }}  \\
 6x+y      &=&10   & &     \\[5mm]  
%
x+4y       &=&-2    &\multirow{2}{*}{\mybrace}& \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{4cm}
{\raggedright text text text text text text text }}  \\
 y         &=&10-6x& &     \\[5mm] 
%
3x+4(10-6x)&=&-2    &\multirow{2}{*}{\mybrace}& \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{4cm}
{\raggedright text text text text text text text }}  \\
 y         &=&10-6x& &     \\[5mm]
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: The switch from math to text is automatic, and \parbox{4cm}{\raggedright...} would also work here.