# How to place braces in multiple equations

Tags: equations, subequations

I have the following expression:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
%C1
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{y^{C_1}_i} &= m\beta_0^{C_1} + \beta_1^{C_1}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_1}} + \cdots + \beta_q^{C_1}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_1}}\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{y^{C_1}_ix_{i1}^{C_1}} &= \beta_0^{C_1}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_1}} + \beta_1^{C_1}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{C_1})^2} + \cdots + \beta_q^{C_1}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_1}x_{i1}^{C_1}}\\
&\vdots\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{y^{C_1}_ix_{iq}^{C_1}} &= \beta_0^{C_1}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_1}} + \beta_1^{C_1}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_1}x_{iq}^{C_1}} + \cdots + \beta_q^{C_1}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{iq}^{C_1})^2}\\
%C2
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{y^{C_2}_i} &= m\beta_0^{C_2} + \beta_1^{C_2}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_2}} + \cdots + \beta_q^{C_2}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_2}}\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{y^{C_2}_ix_{i1}^{C_2}} &= \beta_0^{C_2}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_2}} + \beta_1^{C_2}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{C_2})^2} + \cdots + \beta_q^{C_2}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_2}x_{i1}^{C_2}}\\
&\vdots\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{y^{C_2}_ix_{iq}^{C_2}} &= \beta_0^{C_2}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_2}} + \beta_1^{C_2}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_2}x_{iq}^{C_2}} + \cdots + \beta_q^{C_2}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{iq}^{C_2})^2}\\
%R
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{y^{R}_i} &= m\beta_0^{R} + \beta_1^{R}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{R}} + \cdots + \beta_q^{R}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{R}}\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{y^{R}_ix_{i1}^{R}} &= \beta_0^{R}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{R}} + \beta_1^{R}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{R})^2} + \cdots + \beta_q^{R}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{R}x_{i1}^{R}}\\
&\vdots\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{y^{R}_ix_{iq}^{R}} &= \beta_0^{R}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{R}} + \beta_1^{R}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{R}x_{iq}^{R}} + \cdots + \beta_q^{R}\sum_{i = 1}^{m}{(x_{iq}^{R})^2}
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:normals_equations}
\end{equation}
```

and I want to place brace of this form:

[image]
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic building block you can use is

```
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
     ....
  \end{\aligned}
\right.
```

If you want the `q+1` in front then just write it before the `\left\{`.
You want three such groups on separate lines apparently with one single equation number, so you can place these groups in to

```
\begin{equation}
   \begin{gathered}
      ...\\
      ---\\
   \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
```

giving

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
    \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
        % C1
        \sum_{i=1}^{m}{y^{C_1}_i}
        &= m\beta_0^{C_1}
        + \beta_1^{C_1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_1}} + \dots
        + \beta_q^{C_1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_1}}\\
        \sum_{i=1}^{m}{y^{C_1}_ix_{i1}^{C_1}}
        &= \beta_0^{C_1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_1}}
        + \beta_1^{C_1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{C_1})^2} + \dots
        + \beta_q^{C_1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_1}x_{i1}^{C_1}}\\
        &\vdots\\
        \sum_{i=1}^{m}{y^{C_1}_ix_{iq}^{C_1}}
        &= \beta_0^{C_1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_1}}
        + \beta_1^{C_1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_1}x_{iq}^{C_1}}
        + \dots + \beta_q^{C_1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(x_{iq}^{C_1})^2}\\
      \end{aligned}
    \right.\\
    % C2
    \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
        \sum_{i=1}^{m}{y^{C_2}_i}
        &= m\beta_0^{C_2}
        + \beta_1^{C_2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_2}} + \dots
        + \beta_q^{C_2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_2}}\\
        \sum_{i=1}^{m}{y^{C_2}_ix_{i1}^{C_2}}
        &= \beta_0^{C_2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_2}}
        + \beta_1^{C_2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{C_2})^2} + \dots
        + \beta_q^{C_2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_2}x_{i1}^{C_2}}\\
        &\vdots\\
        \sum_{i=1}^{m}{y^{C_2}_ix_{iq}^{C_2}}
        &= \beta_0^{C_2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{C_2}}
        + \beta_1^{C_2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{C_2}x_{iq}^{C_2}}
        + \dots + \beta_q^{C_2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(x_{iq}^{C_2})^2}\\
      \end{aligned}
    \right.\\
    % R
    \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
        \sum_{i=1}^{m}{y^{R}_i}
        &= m\beta_0^{R} + \beta_1^{R}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{R}}
        + \dots + \beta_q^{R}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{R}}\\
        \sum_{i=1}^{m}{y^{R}_ix_{i1}^{R}}
        &= \beta_0^{R}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{R}}
        + \beta_1^{R}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(x_{i1}^{R})^2} + \dots
        + \beta_q^{R}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{R}x_{i1}^{R}}\\
        &\vdots\\
        \sum_{i=1}^{m}{y^{R}_ix_{iq}^{R}}
        &= \beta_0^{R}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{iq}^{R}}
        + \beta_1^{R}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_{i1}^{R}x_{iq}^{R}}
        + \dots + \beta_q^{R}\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(x_{iq}^{R})^2}
      \end{aligned}
    \right.
    \label{eq:normals_equations}
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I have changed your `\cdots` to `\dots` since `amsmath` knows which dots to use between `+` plus signs.

You might consider using `\vdotswithin{=}` from the `mathtools` package to get the vertical dots to be centered on the equals signs.

If you want to align the various elements vertically across groups, see [Aligning across 'aligned' equation blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1938/15925)