# Efficient way to align columns in cases environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cases

I wanted to know if there was an efficient way to align the first column in a cases environment instead of using the `\phantom` code as I have used below?

The code I did somehow feels like a hack???

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
-\tau \ddot{e} - \dot{e} = %
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}A; & e+T_{L}\dot{e}>0\\
\phantom{-~}0; & e + T_{L}\dot{e}=0\\
-A; & e+T_{L}\dot{e}<0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without `cases`, one could

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
-\tau \ddot{e} - \dot{e} = %
\left\{\begin{aligned}
A; && e+T_{L}\dot{e}&>0\\
0; && 1e + T_{L}\dot{e}&=0\\
-A; && e+T_{L}\dot{e}&<0
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

This also aligns on the right-hand relational operator.

[image]

Alternately, if one desired more control over the equation baselineskip in the case, one could use a TABstack.  The vertical baselineskip is set via `\setstackgap{L}{<length>}`.  Similarly, the horizontal gap between align groups can be set via `\setstackaligngap{<length>}` (default 1em).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.3\normalbaselineskip}% EQ BASELINESKIP SET HERE
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
-\tau \ddot{e} - \dot{e} = %
\left\{\alignCenterstack{
A; && e+T_{L}\dot{e}&>0\\
0; && 1e + T_{L}\dot{e}&=0\\
-A; && e+T_{L}\dot{e}&<0
}\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice +1... Also see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/aligning-across-aligned-equation-blocks for more complicated fanctionality

Answer (score 3):

Use [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` to set all `<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` in a box of maximum width. You can also adjust the `<align>`ment as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

% Original
\begin{equation*}
  -\tau \ddot{e} - \dot{e} = %
  \begin{cases}
     \phantom{-}A; & e + T_{L}\dot{e} > 0 \\
    \phantom{-~}0; & e + T_{L}\dot{e} = 0 \\
               -A; & e + T_{L}\dot{e} < 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

% Updated
\begin{equation*}
  -\tau \ddot{e} - \dot{e} =
  \begin{cases}
    \eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$ A$}; & e + T_L \dot{e} > 0 \\
    \eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$ 0$}; & e + T_L \dot{e} = 0 \\
    \eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$-A$}; & e + T_L \dot{e} < 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Since `eqparbox` uses the `.aux` file to gather the maximum width, you need at least two compilations on the first go (or with any change in the boxes) for the maximum width to be established.

Answer (score 1):

Without `cases`, one could

```
\def\casesR#1{\left\{\vcenter{\openup2pt 
   \halign{\hfil$##$&&\quad\hfil$##$\cr#1\crcr}}\right.}
$$
  -\tau \ddot e - \dot e = \casesR{
     A;  &  e + T_L \dot e > 0  \cr
     0;  & 1e + T_L \dot e = 0  \cr
    -A;  &  e + T_L \dot e < 0  }
$$

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

The  `empheq` package with its `left` key, combined with the `alignat*` environment gives a particularluy simple code. Note you don't have to load `amsmath`, since `empheq` loads `mathtools`, which loads and extends the former:    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{empheq}

```
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left ={-\tau \ddot{e} - \dot{e} =\empheqlbrace}]{alignat* = 2}
A; &\quad& e+T_{L}\dot{e}&>0\\
0; && 1e + T_{L}\dot{e}&=0\\
-A; && e+T_{L}\dot{e}&<0
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]