# Commutative diagram with rounded arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, diagrams, xy-pic

I want to draw a diagram which has some arrows between to points A and B. First arrow goes straight from A to B and above it should be a `$\Psi$`. Second arrow goes in a round way from A to B and above should be a `$\Phi$`. Furthermore there's another one from A to B which has a `$\Omega$`.

Now there should be some `$\Downarrow$`s from `$\Phi$` to `$\Psi$` and from `$\Psi$` (starting below the arrow) to `$\Omega$`.

The drawing below shows an idea of what I want.

[image: example diagram]

I usually use xypic for such kind of diagrams. Thatswhy I tried this first. But I came to no real solution. Ist this possible with xypic and, if yes, how? If not, I assume most would suggest Ti*k*Z. How can I set this with Ti*k*Z?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Xy-pic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\UseAllTwocells

\begin{document}
\xymatrixcolsep{3cm}
\xymatrix{
  A \ruppertwocell^f{\alpha}
    \rlowertwocell_h{\beta}
    \ar[r]|{g}
  &B\\
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {$A$};
  \node[right=4cm of a] (b) {$B$};
  \draw[->]
    (a) edge node[fill=white] (g) {$g$} (b)
    (a) edge[bend left] node (f) [above]{$f$} (b)
    (a) edge[bend right] node (h) [below]{$h$} (b);
  \draw[shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt,-implies]
    (f) edge[double] (g)
    (g) edge[double] (h);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another solution with [pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    >=stealth,
    shorten >=2pt,
    shorten <=2pt,
    auto,
    node distance=5cm
  ]
    \node (a) {A};
    \node (b) [right of=a] {B};

    \path[->] (a) edge                node        (psi)   {$\Psi$}   (b)
              (a) edge [bend left=45] node        (phi)   {$\Phi$}   (b)
              (a) edge [bend right]   node [swap] (omega) {$\Omega$} (b)
              (phi) edge (psi)
              (psi) edge (omega);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a first stab at a tikz solution. It is crude and I'm sure there are libraries that would tidy this up no end! The standalone document class and the `scale` are just to get the picture looking big enough...

```
\documentclass[border=5em]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \node (a)  {$A$};
  \node  (b) [right=of a] {$B$};
  \node (midpoint) at ($(a)!.5!(b)$) {};
  \node (psi) [above=.5cm of midpoint] {$\psi$};
  \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
\draw[->] (a.north east) parabola bend (psi.south) (b.north west);
\draw[->,shorten <=3pt] (psi.south) -- (midpoint.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm using the `positioning` library to be able to use constructions like `\node (b) [right=of a] {$B};` which allows me to position a node `(b)` relative to the position of `(a)`.

I'm using the `calc` library to allow to easily work out the midpoint of the line from `a` to `b` with the `$(a)!.5!(b)$` construction. Other numbers put in the middle there will identify points nearer to `a` or `b`... [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/large-braces-over-several-items-in-an-itemize-with-text-by-the-brace/12399#12399) contains some good examples of using the `calc` library.

I draw a `parabola` that starts at `a` and then `bend`s `south` of the `psi` node, which is `above` the `midpoint` before coming to an end at `b`.

Then I draw another line that starts just `south` of `psi` (and then some: I `shorten` the begining of the path because otherwise it actually overlaps with where the previous line bended...). The line continues to just `north` of `midpoint`.

It should be obvious how to make the other half: make a node `below` the `midpoint` and then do roughly the same thing...

[image: commutative diagram]

Comment: See also, answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3892/215)