# How to draw a line passing through a point and perpendicular to another?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having a bit of a headache right now as I can't draw this basic figure:

**A straight line goes through points A and B. Another line is perpendicular to AB and goes through an arbitrary point P.**

I fiddled with the |- operator but it only seems to work with horizontal or vertical lines. Is this even possible?

Bonus question: when drawing AB, is it possible to let the line poke out a little? For example, when writing **\draw (A) -- (B);** the line strictly goes from A to B. I'd rather have a line passing through these points but starting 1cm in front of A and ending 1cm after B (for example).

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: For the "bonus" question: You could use `shorten >=-1cm,shorten <=-1cm` together with a pseudo-arrow tip to extend the lines.

Comment: @Martin: The `shorten` (note spelling mistake in your comment) keys work independently of arrow tips so it's not necessary to specify an arrow tip.  Thus `\draw[shorten >=-1cm] (0,0) -- (2,0);` will work.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. I figured this out in the meantime. See my comment below Jakes answer.

Comment: @Martin: I know, but some people may not read further and just see the comment here so I thought it worth pointing that out here as well.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library for this, which allows to do coordinate calculations. The expression `($(A)!(P)!(B)$)` yields the projection of `(P)` on the line from `(A)` to `(B)`, for example.

As Martin Scharrer points out, you can extend the lines by using the `shorten >` and `shorten <` commands with negative values. I'm using them here in a style called `extended line` that takes an optional argument to set the length by which to extend the line.

Here's your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\node [dot=A] at (0,0) {};
\node [dot=B] at (3,1) {};
\node [dot=P] at (1.9,-1.6) {};

\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (A) -- (B);
\draw [extended line] ($(A)!(P)!(B)$) -- (P);

\fill [red] ($(A)!(P)!(B)$) circle [radius=2pt];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz projected point]

Comment: Good answer. Note that you should also be able to give length instead of factors, e.g. `($(A)!-1cm!(B)$)` instead of `($(A)!-0.2!(B)$)`. Also `\draw [shorten >=-1cm,shorten <=-1cm] (A) -- (B);` works well for the extension of the line.

Comment: Good idea with the `shorten` commands, that's much more readable!

Comment: The structure of this example would also be clearer if you defined, for example, `\node (Q) at ($(A)!(P)!(B)$);` and made reference to it.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/large-braces-over-several-items-in-an-itemize-with-text-by-the-brace/12399#12399) has a good explanation of this sort of usage of the `calc` library

Comment: Thanks for both the calc advice and the shorten shortcut!

Comment: @Ryan: In that case you really should use `\coordinate` instead of `\node` to avoid issues with borders and minimal size etc.

Comment: @Martin: theoretically yes, but since he is actually drawing a red circle at Q, I think it is okay to roll the node definition in with the `\fill` command at the end of the code he gives.  Though that would require some reorganization and entail some care that the lines are not drawn over the dot, so perhaps I shouldn't argue.

Comment: @Ryan: You can use `coordinate` as part of the path as well. Or you could draw the red dot as `circle` node of course.

Comment: @Martin: That's what I meant about `\fill`ing the circle.

Comment: Excellent answer! I adapted it to: `extend line/.style 2 args={shorten >=-#2,shorten <=-#1}, extend line/.default={1cm}{1cm},` so that I could extend by different lengths left and right.

Answer (score 19):

Here's how to do it using [tkz-euclide](http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/euclide.html); the code is, in fact, a variation of one example given in the [tkz-euclide examples collection](http://www.altermundus.fr/downloads/documents/tkz-geom-main.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(4,2.5){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(4,5){C}
  \tkzDrawLine[add= 0.5 and 0.8,color=blue](A,B)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)
  \tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through C](A,B)
  \tkzDrawLine[add = .5 and .2,color=red](C,tkzPointResult)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: since `tkz-euclide` is on CTAN but it is not included in TeX Live (at least not fot the moment), you'll have to download the files and install them manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think I'll rather use the calc method described above :)

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina  The announcement is not done yet but the new version in on CTAN. I added tkz-graph and tkz-berge. Now on CTAN, there is a directory `tkz` with all my packages based on TikZ. A big part of tkz will be on the next release of TeXLive 2011 (the beginning of July).

Comment: @Altermundus: great! Thank you very much for the notice.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina your imagina is no longer available. Would it be possible to put it back in?

Comment: @Vivi: done. It's a problem with most of the images I uploaded; see this thread on meta: [how-do-we-repair-gonzalo-medinas-posts-containing-images](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1440/how-do-we-repair-gonzalo-medinas-posts-containing-images).

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Oh, wow, I didn't know the proportion of the thing. Thanks for re-uploading the image, and also thanks for all the nice and useful posts  :)

Comment: And I just realised I spelled "image" as "imagina". I think it was because I had just been talking to my mum in Portuguese (my excuse)

Comment: @Vivi: no problem. I understood perfectly ;-)

Answer (score 9):

1) `tkz-euclide` is on CTAN but not on TexLive I need to upload the sources of the documentation.

2) The solution with `calc` it's not effective. The next code is from the `pgfmanual`and I make a zoom on the intersection 
(see The Syntax of Projection Modifiers)

```
\begin{tikzpicture} \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\coordinate (a) at (0,1); 
\coordinate (b) at (3,2); 
\coordinate (c) at (2.5,0);
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
\draw[red]  (a) -- ($(b)!(a)!(c)$); 
\draw[orange] (b) -- ($(a)!(b)!(c)$); 
\draw[blue] (c) -- ($(a)!(c)!(b)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

On some cases, It's impossible to draw geometric picture without errors.
In `tkz-euclide`, if I want a line from A perpendicular to BC,   I define a vector BE perpendicular BC, then a vector AD perpendicular to BC and then I search the intersection of
AD and BC

3) For the extend style, another solution is :

```
\tikzset{%
    add/.style args={#1 and #2}{
        to path={%
 ($(\tikztostart)!-#1!(\tikztotarget)$)--($(\tikztotarget)!-#2!(\tikztostart)$)%
  \tikztonodes}}
}
```

example : the idea is to use percentage add = 1 and 0, double the line, with 1 and 1 we get the triple, and you can use negative numbers

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,
                   fill,label={#1},name=#1},]
\tikzset{%
add/.style args={#1 and #2}{to path={%
 ($(\tikztostart)!-#1!(\tikztotarget)$)--($(\tikztotarget)!-#2!(\tikztostart)$)%
\tikztonodes}}
}

\node [dot=A](A) at (0,0) {};
\node [dot=B](B) at (3,1) {};  
\node [dot=C](C) at (3,-1) {};  
\draw[add = 1 and 0] (A) to (B);
\draw[add = .5 and .5] (A) to (C);      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just another simpler solution with PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\pspicture(8,6)
    \pstGeonode(2,3){A}(6,5){B}(6,2){P}
    \pstProjection[PointName=none]{A}{B}{P}
    \psset{nodesep=-1}
    \pstLineAB{A}{B}
    \pstLineAB{P}{P'}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

### Applications

To answer [this question (click)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197015/19356).

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{esvect}
\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    linejoin=1,
    shortput=nab,
    arrows=->,
}
\begin{document}
\pspicture(8,6)
    \pstGeonode(1,1){A}(2,5){B}(7,3){C}
    \pcline(A)(B)^{$\vv v$}
    \pcline(A)(C)_{$\vv u$}
    \pstProjection{A}{C}{B}
    \pstRightAngle{C}{B'}{B}
    \pstMarkAngle{B'}{A}{B}{$\theta$}
    \psset{linecolor=blue}%
    \everypsbox{\color{blue}}%
    \pcline(B')(B)_{$\vv{v}_{{\scriptscriptstyle\bot}\vv u}$}
    \pcline(A)(B')_{$\vv{v}_{{\scriptscriptstyle\parallel}\vv u}$}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]