# Right Angle Symbol Alignment with TikZ/Calc

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, intersections

I used a solution from @Jake from this post [Insertion of Perpendicular Symbol at Intersection of Two Lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/insertion-of-perpendicular-symbol-at-intersection-of-two-perpendicular-lines), but the alignment is not quite right. I have my suspicions why, but I don't understand the `pgf` code enough to figure it out.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,backgrounds,arrows}   
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
right angle quadrant/.code={
    \pgfmathsetmacro\quadranta{{1,1,-1,-1}[#1-1]}     % Arrays for selecting quadrant
    \pgfmathsetmacro\quadrantb{{1,-1,-1,1}[#1-1]}},
right angle quadrant=1, % Make sure it is set, even if not called explicitly
right angle length/.code={\def\rightanglelength{#1}},   % Length of symbol
right angle length=2ex, % Make sure it is set...
right angle symbol/.style n args={3}{
    insert path={
        let \p0 = ($(#1)!(#3)!(#2)$) in     % Intersection
            let \p1 = ($(\p0)!\quadranta*\rightanglelength!(#3)$), % Point on base line
            \p2 = ($(\p0)!\quadrantb*\rightanglelength!(#2)$) in % Point on perpendicular line
            let \p3 = ($(\p1)+(\p2)-(\p0)$) in  % Corner point of symbol
        (\p1) -- (\p3) -- (\p2) 
                  }
                              }
    }

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,point/.style={name={#1}},sharp corners]
\clip (-0.1,-0.1)   rectangle   (6.1,6.1);
\draw   [step=0.5cm,dotted,line width=0.35pt]   
    (0,0)       grid        (6,6);
%   Parallel Line Graph
%   Axis
\draw   [line width=0.75pt]         (2,0)                   --(2,6)
                                (0,2)                   --(6,2);
%   Lines & Right Angle 
\node   [point=A]                   at                  (5.5,5) {};
\node   [point=B]                   at                  (1,0.5) {};
\node   [point=C]                   at                  (5.5,0.5)   {};
\node   [point=D]                   at                  (0.5,5) {};
\draw   [<->]       (A) -- (B); 
\draw   [<->]       (C) -- (D); 
\draw [right angle quadrant=4,right angle symbol={A}{B}{D}] ($(A)!(D)!(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I imagine the solution is within the macro, but can someone help me understand where?

Comment: The line from `(D)` to `($(A)!(D)!(B)$)` point is rectangular to the line from `(A)` to `(B)`. *Or in other words:* The line from `(A)` to `(B)` and the line from `(C)` to `(D)` do not intersect at `($(A)!(D)!(B)$)`. *Or in other words:* The lines do not intersect in a right angle. — If you use for `(C)` `(5,.5)`, it works. — ***Also:*** **Do not use `node`s if you declare `coordinate`s.**

Comment: Good catch! I guess I should have checked the actual angle of the lines when using `calc`. Regarding the ALSO, should I use `path`? Or some other command?

Comment: `\coordinate (A) at (5.5,5);` would suffice. Almost everything in TikZ is a `\path`. (`\coordinate` simply expands to `\path coordinate` as `\node` does to `\path node`). You can do specify all coordinates in one path: `\path coordinate (A) at (…) coordinate (B) at (…) …;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line from `(D)` to `($(A)!(D)!(B)$)` point is rectangular to the line from `(A)` to `(B)`.

Or in other words: The line from `(A)` to `(B)` and the line from `(C)` to `(D)` do not intersect at `($(A)!(D)!(B)$)`.

Or in other words: The lines do not intersect in a right angle.

If you use for `(C)` `(5,.5)`, it works.

Also do not use `node`s if you declare coordinates, use `coordinate`s instead. The nodes are highlighted (`draw=red`) in this image:

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\tikzset{
    right angle quadrant/.code={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\quadranta{{1,1,-1,-1}[#1-1]}     % Arrays for selecting quadrant
        \pgfmathsetmacro\quadrantb{{1,-1,-1,1}[#1-1]}},
    right angle quadrant=1, % Make sure it is set, even if not called explicitly
    right angle length/.code={\def\rightanglelength{#1}},   % Length of symbol
    right angle length=2ex, % Make sure it is set...
    right angle symbol/.style n args={3}{
        insert path={
            let \p0 = ($(#1)!(#3)!(#2)$),     % Intersection
                \p1 = ($(\p0)!\quadranta*\rightanglelength!(#3)$), % Point on base line
                \p2 = ($(\p0)!\quadrantb*\rightanglelength!(#2)$), % Point on perpendicular line
                \p3 = ($(\p1)+(\p2)-(\p0)$) in  % Corner point of symbol
            (\p1) -- (\p3) -- (\p2)
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,point/.style={name={#1}},sharp corners]
\clip (-0.1,-0.1)   rectangle   (6.1,6.1);
\draw [step=0.5cm,dotted,line width=0.35pt] (0,0) grid (6,6);

\draw  [line width=0.75pt] (2,0) -- (2,6)
                           (0,2) -- (6,2);
\coordinate (A) at (5.5,5);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0.5);
\coordinate (C) at (5,0.5);
\coordinate (D) at (0.5,5);
%\node [draw=red, point=A] at (5.5,5)   {};
%\node [draw=red, point=B] at (1,0.5)   {};
%\node [draw=red, point=C] at (5,0.5) {};
%\node [draw=red, point=D] at (0.5,5)   {};

\draw [<->] (A) -- (B); 
\draw [<->] (C) -- (D); 

\draw [right angle quadrant=4,right angle symbol={A}{B}{D}] ($(A)!(D)!(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]