# How filling angle symbol?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the thread [Insertion of perpendicular symbol at intersection of two perpendicular lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/insertion-of-perpendicular-symbol-at-intersection-of-two-perpendicular-lines), Jake proposed a very useful command to mark a right angle. I tried to color the symbol, but I get only half colored.

```
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
    \tikzset{
     right angle quadrant/.code={
     \pgfmathsetmacro\quadranta{{1,1,-1,-1}[#1-1]}   
     \pgfmathsetmacro\quadrantb{{1,-1,-1,1}[#1-1]}},
      right angle quadrant=1, 
      right angle length/.code={\def\rightanglelength{#1}},   
      right angle length=2ex,
      right angle symbol/.style n args={3}{
      insert path={
        let \p0 = ($(#1)!(#3)!(#2)$) in    
            let \p1 = ($(\p0)!\quadranta*\rightanglelength!(#3)$), 
            \p2 = ($(\p0)!\quadrantb*\rightanglelength!(#2)$) in 
            let \p3 = ($(\p1)+(\p2)-(\p0)$) in 
        (\p1) -- (\p3) -- (\p2)
     }
     }
     }

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1}]

  \begin{axis}[
    restrict x to domain=-4:5, xmax=5, xmin=-4,
    restrict y to domain=-2:4, ymax=4, ymin=-2,
    x=0.7cm,
    y=0.7cm,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    major tick style=black,
    axis line style = thick,
    tickwidth=0.1cm,
    grid=both,
    xtick={-3,...,4},
    ytick={-1,...,3},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,},
    extra x ticks={-4,5}, 
    extra x tick label={\null}, 
    extra y ticks={-2,4}, 
    extra y tick label={\null},
    extra tick style={tick style={draw=none}},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},
   anchor=west,
   },
   every axis y label/.style={
   at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},
   anchor=south,
   },
  samples=1000,
  >=stealth,
  ]


 \coordinate [label=above right : $A$] (A) at (-2,3);
 \coordinate [label=below left : $B$](B) at (-3,1);
 \coordinate [label=above right : $C$](C) at (4,0);
 \coordinate [label=below right : $H$] (H) at ($(B)!(A)!(C)$);

 \draw [thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
 \draw [thick,extended line=3cm] (A)--(H);
 \draw [fill=red,right angle quadrant=1,right angle symbol={B}{C}{A}];

 \node[below=2pt] at (1,0) {$1$};
 \node[left=2pt] at (0,1) {$1$};
 \node[below left=2pt] at (0,0) {$0$};

 \node[thick] at (A) {+};
 \node[thick] at (B) {+};
 \node[thick] at (C) {+};

 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg Sorry, see my edit.

Comment: Replacing `(\p1) -- (\p3) -- (\p2) ` with `(\p1) -- (\p3) -- (\p2) --(\p0)` will fill in the symbol.  If you want that fill, I would recommend you do the fill _before_ you draw the triangle.

Comment: @PeterGrill an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing `(\p1) -- (\p3) -- (\p2)` with `(\p1) -- (\p3) -- (\p2) --(\p0)` will fill in the symbol. The original macro at [Insertion of perpendicular symbol at intersection of two perpendicular lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/insertion-of-perpendicular-symbol-at-intersection-of-two-perpendicular-lines) was designed to draw the perpendiular symbol assuming that the other lines were already in place; Thus, it was not doing a complete cycle.

### Notes:

- In the version below I am using the macro from a follow-up question to the one where you got the code: [Right Angle Symbol Alignment with TikZ/Calc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114680/right-angle-symbol-alignment-with-tikz-calc).  But, for this specfic case either version of the `right angle quadrant=` seems to work fine:
- Also, I recommend filling the symbol in *before* drawing the other lines as I have done below.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114680/right-angle-symbol-alignment-with-tikz-calc
\tikzset{
    right angle quadrant/.code={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\quadranta{{1,1,-1,-1}[#1-1]}     % Arrays for selecting quadrant
        \pgfmathsetmacro\quadrantb{{1,-1,-1,1}[#1-1]}},
    right angle quadrant=1, % Make sure it is set, even if not called explicitly
    right angle length/.code={\def\rightanglelength{#1}},   % Length of symbol
    right angle length=2ex, % Make sure it is set...
    right angle symbol/.style n args={3}{
        insert path={
            let \p0 = ($(#1)!(#3)!(#2)$),     % Intersection
                \p1 = ($(\p0)!\quadranta*\rightanglelength!(#3)$), % Point on base line
                \p2 = ($(\p0)!\quadrantb*\rightanglelength!(#2)$), % Point on perpendicular line
                \p3 = ($(\p1)+(\p2)-(\p0)$) in  % Corner point of symbol
            (\p1) -- (\p3) -- (\p2) --(\p0)%% <-- Added '--(\p0)'
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1}]

\begin{axis}[
    restrict x to domain=-4:5, xmax=5, xmin=-4,
    restrict y to domain=-2:4, ymax=4, ymin=-2,
    x=0.7cm,
    y=0.7cm,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    major tick style=black,
    axis line style = thick,
    tickwidth=0.1cm,
    grid=both,
    xtick={-3,...,4},
    ytick={-1,...,3},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,},
    extra x ticks={-4,5}, 
    extra x tick label={\null}, 
    extra y ticks={-2,4}, 
    extra y tick label={\null},
    extra tick style={tick style={draw=none}},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},anchor=west},
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)}, anchor=south},
    samples=1000,
    >=stealth,
]


 \coordinate [label=above right : $A$] (A) at (-2,3);
 \coordinate [label=below left : $B$](B) at (-3,1);
 \coordinate [label=above right : $C$](C) at (4,0);
 \coordinate [label=below right : $H$] (H) at ($(B)!(A)!(C)$);

 \draw [fill=red, right angle quadrant=1,right angle symbol={B}{C}{A}];
 \draw [thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
 \draw [thick,extended line=3cm] (A)--(H);

 \node[below=2pt] at (1,0) {$1$};
 \node[left=2pt] at (0,1) {$1$};
 \node[below left=2pt] at (0,0) {$0$};

 \node[thick] at (A) {+};
 \node[thick] at (B) {+};
 \node[thick] at (C) {+};

 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```