# Adjust position of node label

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In the MWE below, how can I get to adjust the position of the node labels? Note that the nodes are defined by

```
dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1}
```

but I cannot figure out how to keep the same setting will being able to adjust the positioning of the label. For example, something like `dot=M,left` or `dot=M,right`. The original source of the code is gotten from  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21759/10898

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    right angle quadrant/.code={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\quadranta{{1,1,-1,-1}[#1-1]}     % Arrays for selecting quadrant
        \pgfmathsetmacro\quadrantb{{1,-1,-1,1}[#1-1]}},
    right angle quadrant=1, % Make sure it is set, even if not called explicitly
    right angle length/.code={\def\rightanglelength{#1}},   % Length of symbol
    right angle length=2ex, % Make sure it is set...
    right angle symbol/.style n args={3}{
        insert path={
            let \p0 = ($(#1)!(#3)!(#2)$) in     % Intersection
                let \p1 = ($(\p0)!\quadranta*\rightanglelength!(#3)$), % Point on base line
                \p2 = ($(\p0)!\quadrantb*\rightanglelength!(#2)$) in % Point on perpendicular line
                let \p3 = ($(\p1)+(\p2)-(\p0)$) in  % Corner point of symbol
            (\p1) -- (\p3) -- (\p2)
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\node [dot=L] at (1,0) {};
\node [dot=M] at (4,0) {};
\node [dot=N] at (4,5) {};

\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (L) -- (M) node [below,midway] {3};
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (L) -- (N) node [above left,midway] {6};
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] ($(L)!(N)!(M)$) -- (N) node [right,midway] {$x$};
\draw [red,right angle symbol={M}{N}{L}];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note, what am looking for is to move the `N` to the right, `L` to lower left and `M` to lower right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Syntax for labels is

```
/tikz/label=[<options>]<angle>:<text>
```

where `<angle>` helps you to place labels around its position. In your case, you just need to include this second parameter in `dot/.style` definitition. With something like

```
dot/.style 2 args={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#2:#1},name=#1},
```

you can use `\node [dot={L}{below}] at (1,0) {};`. As usual in `TiKZ` you can use expressions like `below`, `above`, `below left`, ... instead of numerical values.

Drawing order is important in `TiKZ`. With your code, `dots` are drawn before `extended lines`, therefore `dots` appear behind lines. You can put lines behind dots with `backgrounds` library help. It declares a `background layer` and all objects placed on it will appear behind objects drawn on default main layer.

With all these modifications your code could be

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}

\tikzset{
    right angle quadrant/.code={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\quadranta{{1,1,-1,-1}[#1-1]}     % Arrays for selecting quadrant
        \pgfmathsetmacro\quadrantb{{1,-1,-1,1}[#1-1]}},
    right angle quadrant=1, % Make sure it is set, even if not called explicitly
    right angle length/.code={\def\rightanglelength{#1}},   % Length of symbol
    right angle length=2ex, % Make sure it is set...
    right angle symbol/.style n args={3}{
        insert path={
            let \p0 = ($(#1)!(#3)!(#2)$) in     % Intersection
                let \p1 = ($(\p0)!\quadranta*\rightanglelength!(#3)$), % Point on base line
                \p2 = ($(\p0)!\quadrantb*\rightanglelength!(#2)$) in % Point on perpendicular line
                let \p3 = ($(\p1)+(\p2)-(\p0)$) in  % Corner point of symbol
            (\p1) -- (\p3) -- (\p2)
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style 2 args={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#2:#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1,draw=Cerulean},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\node [dot={L}{below right}] at (1,0) {};
\node [dot={M}{below left}] at (4,0) {};
\node [dot={N}{right}] at (4,5) {};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (L) -- (M) node [below,midway] {3};
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (L) -- (N) node [above left,midway] {6};
\draw [extended line=0.5cm] ($(L)!(N)!(M)$) -- (N) node [right,midway] {$x$};
\end{scope}

\draw [red,right angle symbol={M}{N}{L}];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If change the color of the lines, say to Cerulean, then the lines are above the black points. How can I reverse the order?

Comment: @azetina Please, look at the updated answer.

Comment: How to, for example, set the spacing between `N` and its circle to `0ex`?