# Make a TikZ picture automatic

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, best-practices

I'm trying to make this picture in TikZ:

[image: Target image].

I wrote

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\rinn}{2}
\newcommand*{\rout}{3.8}
\newcommand*{\tangle}{37}
\newcommand*{\sangle}{-30}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=above:$T_1$]        (T1) at (\tangle:\rinn);
\coordinate [label=above right:$T_2$]  (T2) at (\tangle:\rout);
\coordinate [label=below right:$S_1$]  (S1) at (\sangle:\rinn);
\coordinate [label=below right:$S_2$]  (S2) at (\sangle:\rout);

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=\rinn];
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=\rout];

\draw (0,0) -- (T2);
\draw (0,0) -- (S2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that looks like

[image: Output].

The image is automatic but the label position needs adjustment every time something is changed, and even then they're not well placed.

- Is `\newcommand` the best way to define a variable for TikZ?
- Is there a way to adjust the label position so that it always stays clear of the other lines?

Comment: Also, the images are somewhat massive. How to resize them?

Comment: You can visit at the link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58878/tikz-set-node-label-position-more-precisely or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153391/adjust-position-of-node-label.

Comment: If you put the labels into separate nodes you will have more flexibility in placement, but automating the placement would require some non-trivial logic.

Comment: What are the domains of variability of your four parameters?

Comment: @PaulGaborit The radii are big enough as they are. I thought it would be easy to have the angles take any value but they shouldn't have to go past 90 or -90.

Comment: @Kurzd Do you want to say that radii are constant?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Not exactly constant, but they could diminish to maybe to 80% of their current length.

Comment: @Kruzd Some constraints as (`\sangle` < `\tangle`) or (`\rinn` < `\rout`) ?

Comment: @PaulGaborit 10 < `\tangle` < 80 and 280 < `\sangle` < 350 would make the output similar to the original image. `\rinn` < `\rout`, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach {\tangle} in {80,79,...,10}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sangle}{-\tangle}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    % constants
    \def\rinn{2}
    \def\rout{3.8}

    % just to fix the global bounding box
    \path circle[radius=\rout cm+5mm+2em];

    \draw (0,0) circle [radius=\rinn];
    \draw (0,0) circle [radius=\rout];

    \coordinate (T1) at (\tangle:\rinn);
    \coordinate (T2) at (\tangle:\rout);
    \coordinate (S1) at (\sangle:\rinn);
    \coordinate (S2) at (\sangle:\rout);

    \draw (0,0) -- (T1) -- (T2);
    \draw (0,0) -- (S1) -- (S2);

    \path (T1) ++(\tangle+45:5mm) node{T1};
    \path (T2) ++(\tangle+45:5mm) node{T2};
    \path (S1) ++(\sangle-45:5mm) node{S1};
    \path (S2) ++(\sangle-45:5mm) node{S2};

  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's way better than I originally expected. I compiled that, and got a 71-page document in qpdfview. How did you get that gif? You got a white border with `\path circle[radius=\rout cm+5mm+2em];` instead of `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm+2em]{standalone}`, and defined the radii with `\def` instead of `\newcommand*`.  Are these personal preferences?

Comment: @Kurzd My fake circle adds a constant bounding box (the `border` option enlarges the bounding box). With `\def`, I can define a local macro event if it is always defined. With `\newcommand`, you may use `\renewcommand`...

Comment: @Kurzd To make the gif, I use `convert` (from ImageMagick): `convert -delay 0 -density 120 doc.pdf doc.gif`

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect solution ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{}

\newcommand*{\rinn}{2}
\newcommand*{\rout}{3.8}
\newcommand*{\tangle}{37}
\newcommand*{\sangle}{-30}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\coordinate (T1) at (\tangle:\rinn);
\coordinate [label=\tangle:$T_2$]  (T2) at (\tangle:\rout);
\coordinate (S1) at (\sangle:\rinn);
\coordinate [label=\sangle:$S_2$]  (S2) at (\sangle:\rout);

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=\rinn];
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=\rout];

\draw (0,0) -- (T1) -- node[near start] {T1}  (T2);
\draw (0,0) -- (S1) -- node[near start] {S1}   (S2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Had no idea the `border` and `tikz` options existed.