# problem at drawing 3D square for right angle with tikz, pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I'm drawing a 3D square for right angle following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163384/14423. That works fine, but I try filling that square and the results isn't the spected:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{ /pgfplots/area style/.style={%
 area cycle list,
 area legend,
 axis on top,
 }}

\newcommand{\RightAngle}[4][5pt]{%
    \draw[fill] ($#3!#1!#2$)
    --($ #3!2!($($#3!#1!#2$)!.5!($#3!#1!#4$)$) $)
    --($#3!#1!#4$) ;
    }

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[scale=0.65,view={130}{30},axis equal,axis on top,axis lines=center,xlabel=$x(t)$,ylabel=$y(t)$,zlabel=$z(t)$,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty]
  \addplot3[thick,->,black,samples y=0] coordinates {(0.261,1.047,1) (0.511,2.047,1)};
  \addlegendentryexpanded{$T(t)$}
  \addplot3[thick,->,color=green,samples y=0] coordinates {(0.261,1.047,1) (0.261,1.047,-0.5)};
 \addlegendentryexpanded{$T'(t)$}
 \addplot3[thick,->,color=red,samples y=0] coordinates {(0.261,1.047,1) (0.261,1.047,-0.125)};
 \addlegendentryexpanded{$N(t)$}
 \addplot3[blue,domain=0:pi,samples y=0] ({x/4},{x},{sin(deg(1.5*x))});
 %\addlegendentryexpanded{$\Ce$}
 \addplot3[mark=*,mark size=1.5pt] coordinates{(0.261,1.047,1)} node{};
 \coordinate (P) at (0.261,1.047,1);
 \coordinate (T) at (0.511,2.047,1);
 \coordinate (N) at (0.261,1.047,-0.125);
 \RightAngle{(T)}{(P)}{(N)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see there is a dotted node and the square for right angle is not filled completely. What am I doing wrong? and how get square filled with dashed lines?

Comment: Where is the dotted node?

Comment: I don't get the output you posted from the code you posted. My output looks rather different.

Comment: How different is? I obtain that picture (maybe I miss some command). Can you show me your output please?

Comment: The dotted node is below `z(t)`

Comment: Oh, OK. It is a dot and not a `dotted` node. I was looking for `dotted` somewhere. You need to specify a suitable compatibility option to get the output you posted. If you run the code you posted, you will probably not get the output you posted unless you've configured defaults somewhere where are not the standard ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using something optimised for an older version of **pgfplots** which gave wrong output, you need to specify a version to get the correct output. At least, that is how I roughly understood the console warnings. Adding the compatibility option `newest` gave me the output posted in the question. So, with [advice from Alenanno](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284600/problem-at-drawing-3d-square-for-right-angle-with-tikz-pgfplots/284626?noredirect=1#comment686822_284626), this could be set to e.g. `1.12` which seems to be the version I get if I ask for `newest`.

When you specify the right angle, you specify from left to right of the bottom and then up to the top right and nothing else. TikZ completes the path using the shortest possible route i.e. from top right to bottom left of the square and fills the result i.e. half of the square. You need to specify that the path goes through `P` before returning to the start point in order to fill the square.

```
\newcommand{\RightAngle}[4][5pt]{%
  \draw[fill] ($#3!#1!#2$) -- ($ #3!2!($($#3!#1!#2$)!.5!($#3!#1!#4$)$) $) -- ($#3!#1!#4$) -- #3  -- cycle;
}
```

I also moved the legend a bit so I could see what I was doing.

[image: filled square]

To fill the square with lines, try the `patterns` library and use `pattern` rather than `fill` for the path. For example:

```
\newcommand{\RightAngle}[4][5pt]{%
  \draw[pattern=north east lines] ($#3!#1!#2$) -- ($ #3!2!($($#3!#1!#2$)!.5!($#3!#1!#4$)$) $) -- ($#3!#1!#4$) -- #3  -- cycle;
}
```

[image: patterned square]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}

\pgfplotsset{ /pgfplots/area style/.style={%
    area cycle list,
    area legend,
    axis on top,
  }}

\newcommand{\RightAngle}[4][5pt]{%
  \draw[pattern=north east lines] ($#3!#1!#2$) -- ($ #3!2!($($#3!#1!#2$)!.5!($#3!#1!#4$)$) $) -- ($#3!#1!#4$) -- #3  -- cycle;
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      scale=0.65,
      view={130}{30},
      axis equal,
      axis on top,
      axis lines=center,
      xlabel=$x(t)$,
      ylabel=$y(t)$,
      zlabel=$z(t)$,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      ztick=\empty,
      legend style={anchor=east}
    ]
    \addplot3[thick,->,black,samples y=0] coordinates {(0.261,1.047,1) (0.511,2.047,1)};
    \addlegendentryexpanded{$T(t)$}
    \addplot3[thick,->,color=green,samples y=0] coordinates {(0.261,1.047,1) (0.261,1.047,-0.5)};
    \addlegendentryexpanded{$T'(t)$}
    \addplot3[thick,->,color=red,samples y=0] coordinates {(0.261,1.047,1) (0.261,1.047,-0.125)};
    \addlegendentryexpanded{$N(t)$}
    \addplot3[blue,domain=0:pi,samples y=0] ({x/4},{x},{sin(deg(1.5*x))});
    %\addlegendentryexpanded{$\Ce$}
    \addplot3[mark=*,mark size=1.5pt] coordinates{(0.261,1.047,1)} node{};
    \coordinate (P) at (0.261,1.047,1);
    \coordinate (T) at (0.511,2.047,1);
    \coordinate (N) at (0.261,1.047,-0.125);
    \RightAngle{(T)}{(P)}{(N)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have to admit I didn't understand the question very well, but using `newest` isn't advisable, because compiling the same code with a newer version that is released later might break the output. I think even the author advised against it somewhere. Better choose a version that gives the desired output and stick with it.

Comment: @Alenanno I just used it because I am not, frankly, familiar with the package and didn't know what version to use. Should I put `1.12`? Is that the current version?

Comment: I think so, but it's not mandatory to use the latest in every case. If `1.10` worked better, then I'd go for it. :D you can try and test. `newest` is not even a problem but it might not be reliable as time goes on.

Comment: @Alenanno I've put `1.12.1` which is what I seem to have. I was really just trying to reproduce the problem in the question. Since this reproduced the problem, for my purposes, no other version could work better ;).

Comment: I guess it doesn't like too much precision... :(. `1.12` seems to work.

Comment: Sounds good to me! :) maybe it doesn't need the extra precision :D

Comment: @cfr really thanks. I miss write `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` in the MWE. Thanks again.