# add right angle symbol to tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, angle, tikz-angles

I realize that there are a bazillion questions on tex.stackexchange about right angle symbols, but all of them (that I can find) seem needlessly complicated, and it's taking me a long time to make sense of the answers.

My question *should* have a very simple answer.  Suppose I have two line segments meeting at a right angle in tikz.  Accordingly, I would like to add a right angle symbol to the diagram.

This can be done "by hand" using a very painstaking process.  But surely there's an automated way to do it.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-] (-12,0) -- (-4.76452,3.41289);
\draw[-] (-5.33333333,4.6188) -- (-4.76452,3.41289);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163344/31034

Comment: @ferahfeza Perfect! Thank you.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this simple enough?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/right angle/.style={code={
\draw ({-abs(#1)},0) |- (0,#1);}},pics/right angle/.default=1]
\draw[-] (-12,0) --  pic[sloped,pos=1]{right angle} (-4.76452,3.41289);
\draw[-] (-5.33333333,4.6188) -- (-4.76452,3.41289);
\begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
\draw[-] (-12,0) --  pic[sloped,pos=1]{right angle} (-4.76452,3.41289)
--([turn]90:1.3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second example shows how you can use `turn` to obtain your original output in a simpler fashion.

Comment: That works too, thanks!