# Drawing of triangle and coordinate system using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using Ti*k*Z for the first time, and I am experiencing some difficulty getting what exactly I want it to display. I am trying to draw the following picture:

[image: wanted]

Here is the code (I know it is not that good, but note it's my first time using Ti*k*Z):

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\draw[thick, ->] (-6,0) -- (10,0) node[anchor = north west] {x};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,-3) -- (0,11) node[anchor = south east] {y};
\node (P) at (-4,-2) {$P(-4;-2)$};
\node (Q) at (8,3) {$Q(8;3)$};
\node (R) at (4,10) {$R(4;10)$};
\node (N) at (2,7) {N};
\draw (P) to (Q);
\draw (R) to (Q);
\draw (P) to (R);
\draw (N) to (Q);
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and it is currently giving me the following:

[image: output]

How can I

- get the point names to *not* cut through the lines,
- draw the line connecting QN to be indicated as a perpendicular line?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please complete your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with `\documentclass` at the start and `\end{document}` at the end.

Comment: That's a pretty good code for a first timer!

Comment: @percusse - Thank you! :). I am just having some difficulty having it give the results I'm looking for .. lol

Comment: For the right angle symbol, you could use the approach from [Insertion of perpendicular symbol at intersection of two perpendicular lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/insertion-of-perpendicular-symbol-at-intersection-of-two-perpendicular-lines)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'll just show one out of many possibilities (and yet another alternative for 90-degrees angle mark - for other angles have a look at the `angles` library in the manual for v3.00-)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]% Scale it rather using too big dimensions in centimeters
\coordinate[label=below:{$P(-4,-2)$}](p) at (-4mm,-2mm);
\coordinate[label=right:{$Q(8,3)$}](q) at (8mm,3mm);
\coordinate[label=above:{$R(4,10)$}] (r) at (4mm,10mm);

\draw (p) -- (q) -- (r) -- cycle; %Look at the tip of the triangle with cycle or (p)
% Here is some black magic; start from q and draw to a point
% which is at the place along the line from p to r but at the 
% place where q is projected on that line.
\draw (q) -- ($(p)!(q)!(r)$) coordinate (s);
\draw ($(s)!0.5mm!(q)$) coordinate (t) -- ($(t)!0.5mm!90:(q)$) --($(s)!0.5mm!(r)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

While you are developing your Ti*k*Z-fu, keep an eye on the package from our own Alain Matthes, called [`tkz-euclide`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide). It makes these kind of drawings really really easy and structured. The only downside is that the manual is French to me (literally). But it is pretty self-explanatory nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you! :). Can you please show me how to get the "perpendicular block" at N from line QN as well? :)

Comment: +1; I have just seen that page 146 of the TikZ manual v3.0 has the exact same solution. `:)`

Comment: This code is very easy to follow :). Thank you! :). It worked wonderfully! How can I label the "projected" line's point as N?

Comment: @PierPaolo Apparently, I subconsciously memorized the TikZ manual.

Comment: Just trying to make it happen to me, too `;)`

Comment: @percusse I am still struggling to get the perpendicular block using this method :( . As for labeling the point N, I simply defined the coordinate manually.

Comment: @Dillon `\draw (q) -- ($(p)!(q)!(r)$)node[draw,pos=1,sloped,anchor=south west]{}node[pos=1.05]{$N$};`.

Comment: @Dillon You can follow the same system `\coordinate[label=above left:{$N$}] (n) at ($(p)!(q)!(r)$);` and then just `\draw (q) -- (n);`. As for the “perpendicular block”, I think there are easy and elegant solutions (even here in TeX.SX) but never payed attention and I can't point at anything (and the same for “angle mark”, I think I saw a `pic` solution that convinced me).

Comment: @Dillon added another possibility. You can add a `left` label to the coordinate `s` if you wish.

Answer (score 19):

With [`tkz-euclide`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=9,ymin=-3,ymax=11]
\tkzAxeXY
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$P(-4,-2)$}](-4,-2){P}
\tkzDefPoint[label=right:{$Q(8,3)$}](8,3){Q}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:{$R(4,10)$}](4,10){R}
\tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R R,P)
\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto P--R](Q)
\tkzGetPoint{N}
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](N)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=red](P,Q,R,N)
\tkzDrawSegment(Q,N)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=lightgray](Q,N,R)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.3](Q,P,R){$\beta$}
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=1cm](Q,P,R)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! :) . How can I label the point of intersection of the projected line onto PR as N?

Comment: @Dillon Please see the edit.

Comment: Gorgeous! Btw, I didn't need the line `\usetkzobj{all}`, which threw an error.

Answer (score 8):

And for comparison, with [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it).

[image]

Note that unlike the warning at the top of the OP diagram, this one **is** drawn to scale...

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
u := 5mm;

% axes
path xx, yy;
xx = (5 left -- 9 right) scaled u;
yy = (3 down -- 11 up) scaled u;
drawarrow xx withcolor .5 white; 
drawarrow yy withcolor .5 white;
label.rt (btex $x$ etex, point 1 of xx);
label.top(btex $y$ etex, point 1 of yy);

% define the points
pair M, N, P, Q, R;
P = (-4, -2) scaled u;
Q = ( 8,  3) scaled u;
R = ( 4, 10) scaled u;
M = yy intersectionpoint (P--R);
N = whatever[P,R]; (N-Q) dotprod (R-P) = 0;
%
% mark the right angle
draw unitsquare scaled 5 rotated angle (Q-N) shifted N withcolor .5 white;
% draw the lines
draw P--Q--R--cycle; draw Q--N;
% add the labels
label.ulft(btex $M$          etex, M);
label.ulft(btex $N$          etex, N);
label.top (btex $R\,(4;10)$  etex, R);
label.rt  (btex $Q\,(8;3)$   etex, Q);
label.lft (btex $P\,(-4;-2)$ etex, P);
% label the angle along the bisector
label(btex $\beta$ etex, P + 20 unitvector(Q+R-2P));
endfig;
end.
```

A little thought about the geometry here, shows us that since `M` is on the y-axis it is half way between `P` and `R` in the x-direction, so it must be the midpoint of `P--R`.  It therefore has co-ordinates `(0,4)`; and the distance from `M` to `Q` is therefore `sqrt(8^2+1^2)=sqrt(65)`, but this is the same as the distance from `R` to `Q`, which is `sqrt(4^2+7^2)=sqrt(65)`; hence `QNR` and `QNM` are congruent triangles, and therefore `N` is the midpoint of `R--M` with coordinates `(2,7)`.  You can use Metapost equation system to confirm this; if you add

```
M = (0,4) scaled u; N = (2,7) scaled u;
```

**after** the implicit definitions already given, then MP gives no error.

Comment: how do you know if it's to scale when we do not know the units of the original? ;-)

Answer (score 8):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-eucl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-eucl) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl,pstricks-add}
\psset{unit = 0.76, PointSymbol = none}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5.3,-3.2)(10,11)
  \pnodes(-4,-2){P}(8,3){Q}(4,10){R}(0,0){O}(0,10){Y}
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-5.3,-3.2)(9.5,10.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \pspolygon(P)(Q)(R)
  \uput[270](P){$P(-4,-2)$}
  \uput[350](Q){$Q(8,3)$}
  \uput[90](R){$R(4,10)$}
  \pstInterLL{P}{R}{O}{Y}{M}
  \pstProjection{P}{R}{Q}[N]
  \pstLineAB{Q}{N}
  \pstLineAB{P}{N}
  \pstRightAngle{P}{N}{Q}
  \pstMarkAngle{Q}{P}{R}{$\beta$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

With the unfairly unkwnown [`mfpic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfpic) package. It is a wide set of (La)TeX macros providing a very convenient interface to either METAFONT or MetaPost, in this case the latter.

Since most are not familiar with this package, I've put a fair number of comments in the following code, hence its relative length.

For those who know a bit about MetaPost, `mfpic` can also embed raw MetaPost instructions which are sometimes more convenient. As I did here to locate the points M and N (which is done by MetaPost in its trademark implicit way), and to draw the right angle mark upon N (thanks to MetaPost transformers).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% MetaPost instead of Metafont as drawing program and labels manager.
% Bounding box based on actual picture dimensions, not on the axes dimensions.
\usepackage[metapost, mplabels, truebbox]{mfpic}
% LaTeX preamble given to MetaPost for its labels management
% (corresponds to the verbatimtex ... etex flags of MetaPost)
\mfpverbtex{%&latex
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \begin{document}}
\setlength{\mfpicunit}{.5cm}
\opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[1]{-5}{9.5}{-3}{11}
    % Points definitions. For MetaPost they are local pairs.
    \setmfpair{P}{(-4, -2)}
    \setmfpair{Q}{(8, 3)}
    \setmfpair{R}{(4, 10)}
    % Point M computed by MetaPost as intersection of y-axis and straight line (PQ)
    \setmfpair{M}{(P -- R) intersectionpoint (origin -- (0, \ymax))}
    % Point N computed by MetaPost as intersection of line (PQ)
    % and the straight line perpendicular to (PQ) going through Q
    \mfsrc{save N; pair N; N = whatever[P, R] = whatever[Q, Q + (R-P) rotated 90];}
    % Mark angle beta with the convenient \arc macro of mfpic
    \store{mark_angle}\arc[a]{P, 0.8, angle(Q-P), angle(R-P)}
    % Mark right angle on N with help of MetaPost transformers
    \setmfvariable{path}{mark_right_angle}
        {((1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1)) zscaled 0.3unitvector(Q-N) shifted N}
    % Actual drawings
    \polygon{P, Q, R}
    \lines{Q, N}
    \doaxes{xy}
    \mfobj{mark_angle}
    \mfobj{mark_right_angle}
    % Labels
    \tlpointsep{2bp} % Offset
    \tlabels{[tc]{(\xmax, 0)}{$x$} [cr]{(0, \ymax)}{$y$}
        [cr]{P}{$P(-4, -2)$} [cl]{Q}{$Q(8, 3)$} [bc]{R}{$R(4, 10)$}
        [br]{M}{$M$} [cr]{N}{$N$} [bl]{point 0.4 of mark_angle}{$\beta$}}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

The `.tex` file is to be typeset by (pdf)LaTeX first, then the resulting `.mp` file by MetaPost, and finally the LaTeX file by (pdf)LaTeX again, to produce the figure below.

[image]