# Difference between -| and |- in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Based on [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/intersecting-lines/) tutorial, I understand symbols `-|` and `|-` are used to draw perpendicular lines.

But I wish to understand the difference between the two.

There are the following related questions:

1. [Insertion of perpendicular symbol at intersection of two perpendicular lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/insertion-of-perpendicular-symbol-at-intersection-of-two-perpendicular-lines)
2. [How to add perpendicular symbol at desired location](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458987/how-to-add-perpendicular-symbol-at-desired-location)
3. [How to Mark Right Angle in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356797/how-to-mark-right-angle-in-tikz)

But none of them seem to use the approach of `-|` and `|-`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/121799

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Understand it as it looks like:

- `-|` is "horizontal line → vertical line":

  ```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (1) node[below] {$(0,0)$};
  \draw (2,2) coordinate (2) node[above] {$(2,2)$};
  \draw (1) -| (2);
  % -------------
  \draw (4,2) coordinate (x) node[above] {$(4,2)$};
  \draw (6,0) coordinate (y) node[below] {$(6,0)$};
  \draw (x) -| (y);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]

  Mathematically, `(x,y) -| (a,b)` and `(x,y) -- (a,y) -- (a,b)` are the same.
- `|-` is "vertical line → horizontal line":

  ```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (1) node[below] {$(0,0)$};
  \draw (2,2) coordinate (2) node[above] {$(2,2)$};
  \draw (1) |- (2);
  % -------------
  \draw (4,2) coordinate (x) node[above] {$(4,2)$};
  \draw (6,0) coordinate (y) node[below] {$(6,0)$};
  \draw (x) |- (y);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]

  Mathematically, `(x,y) |- (a,b)` and `(x,y) -- (x,b) -- (a,b)` are the same.

They are clearly very different.

Answer (score 21):

I'd like to add to [JouleV's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481207/101651) another use of `-|` and `|-`.

Given two nodes, A and B:

- if you use `(A |- B)` you have a point with the *x* coordinate of A and the *y* coordinate of B
- if you use `(A -| B)` you have a point with the *x* coordinate of B and the *y* coordinate of A.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A) {A};
\node[draw, above right =4cm of A] (B) {B};
\node[draw] at (A |- B) {$x$ of A, $y$ of B};
\node[draw] at (A -| B) {$x$ of B, $y$ of A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

PSTricks version for @CarLaTeX's explanation:

- `(A|-B)` (TikZ) = `(A|B)` (PSTricks)
- `(A-|B)` (TikZ) = `(B|A)` (PSTricks)