# How to draw orthogonal vectors using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I have the problem, that I want to draw a vector that is decomposed into two orthogonal parts. A short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=2pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1,color=red},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm,scale=2]
\begin{scope}[rotate=30]
  \node [dot=A] at (1,4) {};
  \node [dot=B] at (2,2) {};
  \node [dot=P] at (4,4) {};
  \draw [->] (A) -- (B);
  \draw [->] (A) -- (P -| B);
  \draw [->] (A) -- ($(B) - (P-|B) + (A)$);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I have the vector `AB`. I want one of the component vecors to be in the direction of `AP`. The other should be orthogonal (as seen).

In the example I solved it using `-|` but this works only if the desired vectors are parallel to the actual axes. I need it for arbitrary points `A`, `B` and `P`.

Can you give me a hint, how to draw it?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19348/how-to-draw-a-line-passing-through-a-point-and-perpendicular-to-another solve your problem?

Comment: Well, if I define a new coordinate at the tip of the vector on the line AP using (A)!(P)!(B) and then doing some calculations this should work. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The projection syntax from the `calc` library also takes an optional angle: `($(A)!(P)!90:(B)$)` is the projection of point `(P)` on the line from `(A)` to `(B)` after that line has been rotated 90 degrees around point `(A)`. This makes it easy to draw the vector components:

[image: decomposing vector into orthogonal components]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style={
        circle,
        inner sep=2pt,
        fill,
        label={#1},
        name=#1,
        color=red
    },
    scale=2]
\begin{scope}
  \node [dot=A,gray] at (1,4) {};
  \node [dot=B,gray] at (2,2) {};
  \node [dot=P] at (4,3) {};
  \node [dot=P2,cyan] at (3,2.5) {};
  \draw [->] (A) -- (B);
  \draw [->,red] (A) -- ($(A)!(B)!(P)$);
  \draw [->,red] (A) -- ($(A)!(B)!90:(P)$);
  \draw [->,cyan] (A) -- ($(A)!(B)!(P2)$);
  \draw [->,cyan] (A) -- ($(A)!(B)!90:(P2)$);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are two styles that do what you want. You have to specify the direction AP as an argument of the style, as shown in my example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzstyle{ortho proj}=[decorate,decoration={show path construction,
lineto code={
    \draw let 
    \p{O} = (\tikzinputsegmentfirst),
    \p{A} = (\tikzinputsegmentlast),
    \p{OA} = ($(\p{A})-(\p{O})$),
    \p{w} = #1,
    \n{dot} =  {\x{w}*\x{OA}+\y{w}*\y{OA}},
    \p{proj} = ($\n{dot}/(veclen(\x{w},\y{w}))^2*(\p{w})$)
    in
    (\p{O}) -- ++(\p{proj});}}]


\tikzstyle{perp proj}=[decorate,decoration={show path construction,
lineto code={
    \draw let 
    \p{O} = (\tikzinputsegmentfirst),
    \p{A} = (\tikzinputsegmentlast),
    \p{OA} = ($(\p{A})-(\p{O})$),
    \p{w} = #1,
    \n{dot} =  {\x{w}*\x{OA}+\y{w}*\y{OA}},
    \p{proj} = ($\n{dot}/(veclen(\x{w},\y{w}))^2*(\p{w})$),
    \p{perp} = ($(\p{OA}) - (\p{proj})$)
    in
    (\p{O}) -- ++(\p{perp});}}]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[ortho proj={(1.5,1)},->] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw[perp proj={(1.5,1)},->] (0,0) -- (2,2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I use the following sort of solution (taken from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20864/412) wonderful answer):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \coordinate (a) at (0.2,0.3);
 \coordinate (b) at (1.3,2.4);
 \draw[->] (a) -- (b) ;
 \tikzAngleOfLine(a)(b){\angle};
\draw[blue,->] (a) -- ++(\angle+90:2);
\draw[green,->] (a) -- ++(\angle-90:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe will be useful for others.