# How to draw two triangles intersect on a common triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw in `tikz` the following image:

[image]

I want to draw two triangles intersecting in the common triangles with the dashed box. However, I am finding it difficult though, could anyone help me please?

This is my code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
a \arrow[r, "\lambda"] & b \arrow[r, "\mu"] \arrow[d,"\pi"] & c \arrow[r,"\ell"] \arrow[d,"\rho" ]   & s \arrow[d,"\ell^\prime"]                 &                           \\
                  & d \arrow[r,"\sigma" ] \arrow[lu,  squiggly]      & e \arrow[r,"\mu^\prime"] \arrow[d, "\phi"]   & x \arrow[r,"\theta"] \arrow[d,"\rho^\prime" ]               & a[2] \arrow[d]               \\
                  &                             & p \arrow[r,"\sigma^{\prime}"] \arrow[lu, squiggly] & y \arrow[r,"\theta^\prime"] \arrow[d]          & b[2] \arrow[d]    \\
                  &                             &                             & z \arrow[r,"\nu"] \arrow[lu, squiggly] & c[2] \arrow[d,"\ell{[2]}"]      \\
                  &                             &                             &                                     & s[2] \arrow[lu,  squiggly]
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I would not use `tikz-cd` for this, but just Ti*k*Z which should be much simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes sure, could you help me with how we can do that in TikZ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not quite sure whether the two triangles still should have their outline showing when they intersect or not, both options are shown in the picture.
Here I opted for the latter.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, quotes}
\tikzset{
  above'/.style={above=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude},
  right'/.style={right=\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude},
  brace settings/.style={amplitude=4pt},
  brace length/.initial=.75cm,
  pics/brace'/.style={/tikz/rotate=180, brace={#1}},
  pics/brace/.style={
    /tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code={
      \draw[decorate, decoration={name=brace, /tikz/brace settings}]
      ({-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/brace length})},3pt)
      -- node[midway,style/.expand once=\tikzpictextoptions]{\tikzpictext}
      ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/brace length}},3pt);}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (tl) at (0,0);
\coordinate (br) at (5,-5);
\coordinate (tr) at (tl-|br);
\coordinate[shift={(-2,-1.5)}] (bl-rect) at (tr);
% or with calc library
% \coordinate(bl-rect) at ($(tr)+(-2,-1.5)$);

% bl-rect|-0,0 is just a point above or below of bl-rect
% bl-rect-|0,0 is just a point left or right of bl-rect
\coordinate (bl-rect-y) at (intersection of bl-rect--bl-rect|-0,0 and tl--br);
\coordinate (bl-rect-x) at (intersection of bl-rect--bl-rect-|0,0 and tl--br);

\filldraw[gray, fill=gray!50] (bl-rect) -- (bl-rect-y) -- (bl-rect-x) -- cycle;

\draw (bl-rect) |- pic[near end,  "$\Delta$"  above'] {brace'} (tl) -- (br)
                |- pic[near start,"$\Delta'$" right'] {brace'} cycle;
\draw[dash pattern=on 4\pgflinewidth off 1.5\pgflinewidth]
  (tr) rectangle ([shift={(3pt,3pt)}]bl-rect);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: [More on `intersection of` and alternative solutions via the `intersections` library.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659568)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can we label these two triangles?

Comment: I want to label the two triangles one is \delta and another is \delta^{\prime} in the place of the arrow in the diagram above. thank you

Comment: @Ali I've updated my answer, using the `brace` decoration inside a pic along the path. It's a little bit convoluted but I hope it is easy to use.

Comment: Thank you very much,  it is really useful.

Comment: I have updated my question, could you please help me with how I can add arrows inside the triangles and frame the below triangle? thank you

Comment: @Ali I don't quite understand, where's the gray small rectangle coming from? How does it relate to the rest of the diagram?

Comment: it is just the label of the row in the \Delta triangle

Comment: and the  vertical gray column is in the \Delta^{\prime}

Comment: because this picture of two triangles (\Delta, \Delta^\prime} intersecting in  (\Delta^\prime \prime}

Comment: Hi Qrrbrbirlbel, Can you please help me with that if you have an idea how we can do that