# Align arrows orthogonally to the line array

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
            \draw (-1+0.1*\x,1+0.1*\x) -- (1+0.1*\x,-.5+0.1*\x);
        }

        \draw[->,thick, xshift=5mm,yshift=2mm] (0,0) -- (0,0.2) node (r1) [right] {}; 
        \draw[->,thick, xshift=15mm,yshift=5mm] (0,0) -- (0,0.2) node (r1) [right] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

What do I have to do so that the arrows are orthogonal to the lines and their origin begins exactly at a line?

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19349/31034

Answer (score 2):

For every line "i" I added two points "Ai" and "Bi" (you can add more if you need) which can be used as starting points of vectors

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
            \draw (-1+0.1*\x,1+0.1*\x) -- (1+0.1*\x,-.5+0.1*\x)
             coordinate[pos=.8](A\x) coordinate[pos=.7](B\x);
        }

        \draw[->,thick] (B2) -- +(0.1,0.1) node (r1) [right] {}; 
        \draw[->,thick] (A8) -- +(0.1,0.1) node (r1) [right] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If we could improve [Salim Bou](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/54817/salim-bou)'s answer a little more.

```
\documentclass[margin=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{\x*100};
            \draw (-1+0.1*\x,1+0.1*\x)coordinate(\x) -- (1+0.1*\x,-.5+0.1*\x)coordinate(\y) ;}     

       \coordinate (E0) at ($ (1)!.75!(100) $);  
       \draw[-latex,red] (E0) --++ (45:0.15);

       \coordinate (E1) at ($ (3)!.25!(300) $);  
       \draw[-latex,orange] (E1) --++ (45:0.35); 

       \coordinate (E2) at ($ (5)!.8!(500) $);  
       \draw[-latex,blue] (E2) --++ (45:0.45); 

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]