# Vertical braces spanning multiple items in an ennumeration-like environment

Tags: braces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Large braces over several items in an itemize with text by the brace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/large-braces-over-several-items-in-an-itemize-with-text-by-the-brace)

How can I create these vertical braces if I have something like an enumeration environment and want to but a vertical brace on the right the items from the environment, where the brace may span multiple items, like this:

[image]

So I want to create these to braces next to which I can write some text (indicated with "blabla" in the picture above - which I created using some image manipulating programs).

Comment: have you seen [large-braces-over-several-items-in-an-itemize-with-text-by-the-brace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/large-braces-over-several-items-in-an-itemize-with-text-by-the-brace)

Comment: ok, that's great! we'll close it as a duplicate then :)