# Is it possible to double underbrace?

Tags: braces

```
$$\ln(L)\approx\ln(L_0) + \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_n}_{=\dfrac{n}{\mu}-\large{1}}(\mu-n) + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^2}\bigg|_n\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2!}$$
```

From the above, I need another underbrace beneath

```
$${\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_n}$$
```

This is what I tried:

`$$\ln(L)\approx\ln(L_0) + \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_n}_{\underbrace{=\dfrac{n}{\mu}-\large{1}}_{\text{from (2)}}(\mu-n) + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^2}\bigg|_n\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2!}$$`

Any ideas, thanks

Comment: Have you considered using _TikZ_ for making the braces? **[Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text)** and **[here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/large-braces-over-several-items-in-an-itemize-with-text-by-the-brace)** are examples of how it could be done.

Comment: Please see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean by double underbrace, but it's just as possible as [double rainbows](https://youtu.be/OQSNhk5ICTI):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \ln(L) \approx \ln(L_0) + \underbrace{\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_n}_{=\tfrac{n}{\mu} - 1}}_{abc}(\mu-n)
    + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^2}\bigg|_n\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2!}
\]

\[
  \ln(L) \approx \ln(L_0) + \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_n}_{=\underbrace{\tfrac{n}{\mu} - 1}_{abc}}(\mu-n)
    + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^2}\bigg|_n\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2!}
\]

\[
  \ln(L) \approx \ln(L_0) + \underbrace{\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_n}}_{=\tfrac{n}{\mu} - 1}(\mu-n)
    + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^2}\bigg|_n\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2!}
\]

\end{document}
```

You merely have to add an `\underbrace` around (inside or outside) the existing `\underbrace`.

Comment: Excellent answer, precisely what I needed to see