# Why does Beamer create multiple slides, each updated with the next item, in an itemize environment?

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'm making a presentation in Beamer, and upon adding a certain number of items in an itemize environment, Beamer creates multiple slides. Each successive slide has one more item added to it. For example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Project Objective}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is the first item.
\begin{itemize}
\item Subitem1
\item Subitem2
\end{itemize}
\item This is the second item.
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Subitem3
%\item Subitem4
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces one slide: [image: One slide with all items and subitems 1-3]

However, uncommenting Subitem 4 produces two slides:[image: Two slides with all items. The first includes subitems 1-3, the second includes subitems 1-4.]

Adding subsequent subitems creates subsequent slides, each with another subitem added. Adding subsequent items does not create more slides; each new item appears on all slides, indented below where the last subitem should have been. What causes this?

Comment: Because of `[<+->]`

Comment: Ah, that was left in from me trying to get a right bracket working [as per this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/large-braces-over-several-items-in-an-itemize-with-text-by-the-brace#12395). Thanks for pointing it out, removing it fixed the problem. What does that part do?

Comment: @zaen, it is exactly to create new overlays for each item, so a new page on pdf file will be created. If you want a kind of pause before each item, it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read up on what is referred to as "overlay specification" within the [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). Here is an excerpt (taken from section **3.10 Using Overlay Specifications**):

> The overlay specifications are given in pointed brackets. The specification `<1->` means “from slide 1 on.” [...] `beamer` automatically computes the number of slides needed for each frame. More generally, overlay specification are lists of numbers or number ranges where the start or ending of a range can be left open. For example `-3,5-6,8-` means “on all slides, except for slides 4 and 7.”

Note the different use of *frame* and *slide*. Each frame may have multiple slides associated with it. The overlay specification is designed to identify the number of slides for each frame. There are verbatim overlay specifications, like `\only`, `\onslide` and some "optional arguments" to macros like `\item`.

For `itemize` (lists in general, and other structures like `frame`), you can specify an *incremental overlay specification* `<+->` that inserts the appropriate pause at possibly-sequential items, like lists. Read more about this in section **9.6.4 Incremental Specifications**.