# Chemical equation in the website header?

Tags: equations, chemstyle

How was the chemical equation created that can be seen in the website header (picture) next to the big {TeX}-sign (left) and below the sindarin(?) part?

I assume this was done using TeX somehow (wild guess :D), but I would really like to know whether it was done manually (if this is even possible) or which macro package was used, as it looks really neat.

Comment: Because this question is about (La)TeX and not the TeX.SX site itself, even if it is referenced, it belongs on the main site. I will migrate it there. Then the issue with the forced tag disappears as well.

Comment: This has been more or less answered (indirectly) [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18145/215)

Comment: @Martin: Oh, ok. I thought it belongs into the meta section, sorry.

Comment: @Seamus: Thanks, I should have searched a little harder I guess.

Comment: No problem. This case is a little confusing. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18145/oxidation-reduction-arrows-overhead-and-below-with-oxidation-numbers-also/18203#18203), the code comes from [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/oxidation-and-reduction/).

[There are easier ways to do this, though.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18145/215)