# How do I write oxidation numbers using chemmacros in mathjax?

Tags: mathjax, mhchem, chemmacros

[I saw this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18145/oxidation-reduction-arrows-overhead-and-below-with-oxidation-numbers-also) and went to [chemmacros](https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros-manual.pdf). I'm unable to use the chemmacros package to write oxidation numbers.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I wrote the following, but I can't render oxidation numbers in mathjax in chemistry stack exchange.

$$\require{chemmacros} \ce{\ox{+1,Na}}$$

[image]

Why is my code not working?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How is your problem related to LaTeX? If it is. please provide complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Note that mathjax questions are generally off topic here as they have nothing to do with latex and friends. It is just a javascript library that knows how to render a subset of LaTeX syntax. Unless explicitly stated on the mathjax website, don't expect that X thing is supported by mathjax.

Answer (score 3):

chemmacros and mhchem are two distinct packages. LaTeX and MathJax are two distinct products (with MathJax trying to be very compatible to LaTeX syntax). A chemmacros version for MathJax does not exist, as far as I know. But you could use mhchem like this

```
$\ce{Na^I, Ca^{II}, S^{-II}, F^{-I}}$
```

For the full syntax options, please refer to the [mhchem for MathJax manual](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). You can search for "oxidation" or try the example with the "test drive" at the very bottom. You can ask questions at http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/ using the mhchem tag.