# Curly brace to insert something into an equation? Like an inverted underbrace

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I have a generic equation, into which I want to "insert" something so that the reader can see what I inserted into the equation and at which point.

E.g.

```
\documentclass{plain}

\begin{document}
\[ f = < x | R y > \]

Insert $\int d^3 p |p> <p|$ = 1 before y.
\end{document}
```

What I imagine is a horizontal curly brace, which extends underneath the equation, and which has its tip touching a spot just slightly to the left of the `$y$`, while in the brace there is written `$\int d^3 p |p> <p|$`. It would look something like an inverted `\underbrace{foo}_{bar}`, but I have no idea how to achieve something like that.

In ASCII art this would maybe look like this:

```
f = <x | R y >            (1)
        __|__
   ____|     |____
  | Insert here! |
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a variant of Gonzalo's code that uses `\mathop{}\limits` instead of `\raisebox`. The output is almost the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  f = \langle x | R\mathclap{\mathop{}\limits_{\overbrace{
                   \textstyle\int d^3 p |p\rangle \langle p|}}}y
      \rangle 
\]
\end{document}
```

---

If you want something more flexible, use the `\braceinsert` macro from the code below. It takes one optional argument (the amount by which the brace should be lowered, with default `0ex`) and one mandatory argument (the stuff you want under the brace). Moreover, it takes care of the case that the `\braceinsert` is surrounded by `\left...\right` delimiters, like this:

[image: example for \braceinsert]

To be precise, you'll have to use `\bileft...\biright` instead of `\left...\right` (like `b`race`i`nsert left and right). After the outermost `\biright`, only *explicit* superscripts will work, so instead of `'` you'd have to use `^\prime`. (Subscripts won't work properly, but I don't know when one would want one.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength{\textwidth}{11cm}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{left@right}
\newcommand*\bileft[1]{\left#1\stepcounter{left@right}}
\newcommand*\biright[1]{\right#1%
    \@ifnextchar^{\with@superscript}{\without@superscript}}
\def\with@superscript^#1{^{#1}\without@superscript}
\def\without@superscript{%
    \addtocounter{left@right}{-1}%
    \ifnum\theleft@right=0
      \vphantom{\brace@insert@strut}
      \gdef\brace@insert@strut{}
    \fi
    }
\def\brace@insert@strut{}
\newcommand{\braceinsert}[2][0ex]{%
    \def\insert@material{%
        \mathop{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{0pt}}\limits_{\overbrace{#2}}%
        }%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\brace@insert@strut
        \expandafter{\insert@material}
    \ifnum\theleft@right>0
      \smash{\mathclap{\insert@material}}
    \else
      \mathclap{\insert@material}
    \fi
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
In the formula
\[
  f = 5 \bileft( b^2 + \langle x | R
      \braceinsert[0.2ex]{\textstyle\int d^3 p |p\rangle \langle p|}
      y \rangle \biright)^2,
\]
the depth of the stuff under the brace is added only \emph{after}
\verb|\biright)^2|.
\end{document}
```

<sup>(Maybe this is *wayyy* too complicated?)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the addition. However, with `\mathop{}\limits` you run into the problem that you cannot change the vertical placement of the overbrace. That makes it protrude into the actual equation (that, of course, depends on the equation; in the example though it happens).

Do you maybe know how to adjust the placement?

Comment: @mSSM: See my edit.

Comment: Ha, fun. Thanks for that solution. Just curious - why did you come up with it? Were you not satisfied with the raisebox solution given above? Btw, one minor downside of both solutions is that it "blows up" the vertical size of the content inside the braces. E.g., if I wanted to do \left\langle ... \right\rangle, LaTeX would make those huuuuuge. The obvious work-around would be to use manual sizes from the \big{l,r} family.

Comment: @mSSM: The reason why I was not _quite_ satisfied with Gonzalo's nice answer was that the `4ex` in `\raisebox{-4ex}` has to be guessed. In my solution, the vertical placement is _almost_ OK, which makes the guessing at least simpler. You're right with the `\left...\right` downside; it was not so easy to come up with a solution. See my edit! (Maybe it's way too complicated, I don't know.)

Comment: (hm, I can't @ your name; it won't show it in autocompletion) -- I like your solution a lot. It actually looks very elegant and is more semantic than the previous solution. I think I am going to adapt this in my code. Thanks a lot! Can I change my favourite answer, or is that considered impolite?

Comment: @mSSM: (That's by design, see [Don't remove the @ part of my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97283) `:-(`) My solution has a serious drawback at the moment: it doesn't work with `amsmath` environments like `gather`. I'll look into that. So I wouldn't accept this answer _as is_. But in principle you can change your favourite answer; I'd just recommend a short explanation in a comment to the previous answerer.

Comment: Ah, thank you for mentioning that. Since I am only using AMSmath environments this would be a rahter significant drawback indeed! :D

Comment: @mSSM: OK, now it works with `amsmath`, but you'll have to use `\bileft...\biright` around `\braceinsert`s (`b`race `i`nsert left and right).

Comment: @mSSM: There was another bug in the code; superscripts were not placed properly after the last `\biright`. This is repaired now. Maybe there are more bugs, but I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 17):

Ok, before people wonder what happened to the `tikz` solution, here is an alternate method, using, well... `tikz`.  `\tikzmark` is used to name the location in the equation that you want to refer to. This name is then given to `\Insert` along with various options to control the behavior of the brace and the line connecting them.

[image]

The parameters passed to `\Insert` are:

`#1`. Vertical shift to be applied to the brace

`#2`. Options to control the behavior of the connecting line.

`#3`. Name of the marker in the equation.

`#4`. Text to be braced, which is to be inserted.

### Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to  do the drawing.
- Probably will have issues if the text begin inserted is not on the first line as the arrow will probably overlap other text.

### References:

- The brace is adapted from [adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1568/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\BraceAmplitude}{0.5em}%
\newcommand*{\Insert}[5][0.0ex]{%
    \tikzmark{a}#5\tikzmark{b}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=\BraceAmplitude},decorate,ultra thick,blue,#2]
        ($(a.north)+(0,#1)$) -- ($(b.north)+(0,#1)$);
\draw [thick, blue, #3] ($(a.north)!0.5!(b.north)+(0,#1)+(0,\BraceAmplitude+2pt)$) to (#4);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\[ f = < x | R \tikzmark{MyMarker} y > \]

\bigskip
In the above equation, we need to insert \Insert[1.5ex]{orange}{out=90, in=-90,->,shorten >=-1pt}{MyMarker}{$\int d^3 p |p> <p| = 1$} before $y$.

\[ f = < x | R \tikzmark{MyMarkerA} y \tikzmark{MyMarkerB}> \]

\bigskip
Insert \Insert[1.5ex]{blue}{out=90, in=-90,->,shorten >=-1pt,red}{MyMarkerA}{$\int d^3 p |p> <p| = 1$} before $y$, and some more
\Insert[1.0ex]{brown}{out=135, in=-70,->,shorten >=-2pt}{MyMarkerB}{\textbf{stuff}} after $y$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do those `\tikz` commands work with the `externalize` library?

Comment: @mSSM: Hmmm... Had not considered that. If you can compose a MWE that shows the problem that would be an excellent question to post considering how widely `\tikzmark` is used.  If it is a problem you'd probably have to disable externalization for the pictures that use `\tikzmark`, unless some came up with a better solution.

Answer (score 15):

Here's one possible solution (in LaTeX2e) using an `\overbrace` and `\mathclap` (from the `mathtools` package); the vertical position was adjusted using `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  f = < x | R\mathclap{\raisebox{-4ex}{$\overbrace{\textstyle\int d^3 p |p> <p|}$}} y > 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also would suggest you to use `\langle`, `\rangle` instead of the relational symbols `<`, `>`a:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  f = \langle x | R\mathclap{\raisebox{-4ex}{$\overbrace{\textstyle\int d^3 p |p\rangle \langle p|}$}} y \rangle 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were too fast.

Comment: That `\raisebox` trick is pretty cool. Thanks alot!

And yeah - I am of course using \langle and \rangle, and all that other stuff that is out there (like \lvert). I just did not want to clutter the example. :-)

Comment: I have changed my accepted answer to the one given by Hendrik Vogt. The code is a tad more elegant as it removes a lot of logic from the document itself, and also has a better default placement (as compared to the raisebox method). See the comments below the answer.