# Placing text under an entire math expression

Tags: math-mode

I want to place text under an entire multivariate expression, exactly the way one is able with `\underbrace`, but without the brace. I want it to specifically describe the first variable in the expression, but for the text to span the entire expression. I have scoured the webs and it's all about placing text under single symbols or commands. For example, `\underset`, `\smashoperator`, and `\limits` can't seem to function with more than one command or variable, even when I use brackets around the command line.

I got what I wanted using this:

```
    \begin{align*}
      N_{e}(r)\, =\, \sum_{u, v, w}\; &n_{e}\,(\overrightharp{\text{r}}\, -\,  u\overrightharp{\text{a}}\, -\, v\overrightharp{\text{b}}\, -\,  w\overrightharp{\text{c}}) \\[-.4cm]
       & \lcurvearrownw \text{\footnotesize{electron density per}}\\[-.2cm]
       &\; \; \; \; \; \; \; \text{\footnotesize{primitive unit cell.}}
    \end{align*}
```

but I was wondering if there was a less hacky way of going about it. I want my client to be able to feasibly edit their documents when I am finished. In other words, I want them to know what is going on here.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: One way to do this would be to use `\tikzmark`: You could use something like [Asymmetric overbrace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68526/asymmetric-overbrace/68537#68537) and use `draw=none` so that that brace is not drawn, or if you want something more elaborate [Curly brace to insert something into an equation? Like an inverted underbrace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47017/curly-brace-to-insert-something-into-an-equation-like-an-inverted-underbrace/47032#47032).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `\parbox` to write the text; using `\mathrclap` (from the `mathtools` package) and `\raisebox` you can place the `\parbox` in the desired position; here's a simple example using a defined command `\Desc` with two mandatory arguments (the box width and the text) and one optional argument controlling the vertical shifting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,MnSymbol,harpoon}

\newcommand\Harp[1]{%
  \overrightharp{\textrm{#1}}}
\newcommand\Desc[3][-2.5ex]{%
  \mathrlap{\raisebox{#1}{$\lcurvearrownw$ \parbox[t]{#2}{\footnotesize #3}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
N_{e}(r) = \sum_{\mathclap{u, v, w}}\, n\Desc{3cm}{electron density per \\ primitive unit cell.}_{e}(\Harp{r} - u\Harp{a} - v\Harp{b} - w\Harp{c}) 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you are using the command `\lcurvearrownw` I assumed that you were loading the `MnSymbol` package; this package changes many symbols.

Comment: The usual caveat that `MnSymbol` changes many symbols should appear.

Comment: Thank you @ Gonzalo, that is much simpler than my original solution and I've noted MnSymbol's potential problems.