# Underline number in two parts; math mode

Tags: math-mode, braces

I'm trying to underbrace a binary numeral as follow:

```
  10111101
  '--''---'
    B   D
```

in order to show the binary-hexadecimal correspondence, but using twice the underbrace command:

```
\underbrace{1011}_B\underbrace{1101}_D
```

I get, obviously, two different "words":

```
  1011 1101
  '--' '---'
    B    D
```

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\underbrace is defined in`fontmath.ltx` (part of LaTeX kernel for math stuff) as follows (shortened):

```
\def\underbrace#1{\mathop{...}\limits}
```

The construct is defined as math operator (`\mathop`). This way the lower limit can easily be specified as subscript. But TeX will add a thin space between two `\mathop` atoms.

This space can be removed by adding a negative thin space `\!`. Or the whole underbrace construct can be put into curly braces (subformula). Then it becomes an ordinary math atom (`\mathord`), where TeX will not add spaces inbetween.

The following example shows the differences between the two methods:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  a
  \underbrace{1011}_B
  \!
  \underbrace{1101}_D
  b
\]
\[
  a
  {\underbrace{1011}_B}
  {\underbrace{1101}_D}
  b
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend using `tikzmark`:

[image]

The parameters passed to `\InsertUnderBrace` are:

- `[#1]` tikz draw options,
- `[#2]` tikz brace options,
- `{#3}` name of left `\tikzmark`,
- `{#4}` name of right `\tikzmark`,
- `{#5}` text to be placed under the brace.

### Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to  do the drawing.
- This uses the `\InsertUnderBrace` from [Asymmetric overbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68526/asymmetric-overbrace/68537#68537).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

% Tweak these as necessary
\newcommand*{\BraceAmplitude}{0.4em}%
\newcommand*{\BraceAspect}{0.5}% 
\newcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{0.4ex}%  
\newcommand*{\HorizontalOffset}{0.0em}% 


\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertUnderBrace}{%
    O{} % #1 = draw options
    O{} % #2 = optional brace options
    m   % #3 = left tikzmark
    m   % #4 = right tikzmark
    m   % #5 = text to place underbrace
}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace, amplitude=\BraceAmplitude, aspect=\BraceAspect, #2}, decorate, thick, draw=blue, text=black, #1]
        ($(#4)+(\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$) -- 
        ($(#3)+(-\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$)
        node [below=\VerticalOffset, midway] {#5};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%


\begin{document}
$\tikzmark{Left Mark} 1011 \tikzmark{Middle Mark} 1101 \tikzmark{Right Mark}$ 
\InsertUnderBrace[blue]{Left Mark}{Middle Mark}{B}%
\InsertUnderBrace[red]{Middle Mark}{Right Mark}{D}%
\end{document}
```