# Lower overbrace in math environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I would like to achieve the following inside an math environment
[image]

But I can't get the text below the equation

```
\operatorname{min} \left|
\overbrace{\text{Hadamard product}}^{\begin{pmatrix}
X \circ X \end{pmatrix}} - \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & M \end{pmatrix}
\right|^2
```

results in:
[image]

Comment: Use `\underbrace`

Comment: In this special case I personally like the overbrace more and underbrace does not solve the problem, the brackets get to big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that doesn't need box measurements. I define a command `\setbelow` with one optional and two mandatory arguments. With the optional argument, the stuff below can be lowered more if needed. The result is essentially the same as in [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95909):

[image: output]

For a more flexible solution that also works with `\left` and `\right` see [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59993).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*\setbelow[3][0ex]{%
  \mathop{#2\rule[-#1]{0pt}{0pt}}_{\mathclap{#3}}%
  }
\begin{document}
\[
  \min \bigl|
  \bigl( X \mathbin{\setbelow[0.2ex]{\circ}
                    {\overbrace{\scriptstyle\text{Hadamard product}}}} X \bigr)
  - \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & M \end{pmatrix}
  \bigr|^2
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that you can simply write `\min` instead of `\operatorname{min}`!

Comment: I accepted your answer, because I specially like that everything is warped in a single command

Answer (score 6):

[`abraces`](http://ctan.org/pkg/abraces) can be used for this - swapping/mixing  ofthe brace directions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abraces,mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{abraces,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setbox9=\hbox{$(X \circ X)$}
  \operatorname{min} \big| 
    \mathrlap{\hspace{.5\wd9}\mathclap{\aunderbrace[L1U1R]{\scriptstyle\phantom{\text{Hadamard product}}}_{\text{Hadamard product}}}}
    (X \circ X) - (1 \ 2 \ 3 \ \cdots \ M )\big|^2
\]
\[
  \operatorname{min} \big| 
    \underbrace{(X \circ X)}_{\mathclap{\text{Hadamard product}}}
    - (1 \ 2 \ 3 \ \cdots \ M )\big|^2
\]
\end{document}
```

The use of `\box9` is just for finding the correct width of `(X \circ X)`. That is, some box movement is required in order to place the `\aunderbrace` at the correct location. The second option looks better though.

You could use an `\overbrace` as well. And, using `\big` (and friends) instead of `\left`...`\right` allows for a better appearance in terms of the absolute delimiters.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks for the fast answer

Comment: I think it's best practise to always use `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead of `\big`. Otherwise you may get wrong spacing, e.g. for `\big|\sin x\big|`.