# Using \underbrace with table columns

Tags: tables, arrays

I have the following code:

```
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c}
   p
 & q
 & p\lor{}q
 & p\land{}q \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
```

I'd like to place an `\underbrace` under the last two columns, but can't find any TeX/LaTex manuals indicating how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). For future reference, please keep in mind that while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to play around with the spaces used inside of `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c}
      p
    & q
    & p\lor{}q
    & p\land{}q \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{%
      \raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{%
      \rlap{$\underbrace{\hphantom{\mbox{$p\lor{}q$\hspace*{\dimexpr4\arraycolsep+\arrayrulewidth}$p\land{}q$}}}_{\ell}$}}%
    }
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

The last two columns have the combined width of

- `$p\lor{}q$` (third column heading)
- `$p\land{}q$` (fourth column heading)
- `4\arraycolsep` (two on either side of the two headings, totalling 4)
- `\arrayrulewidth` (between the two headings)

The addition of `\multicolumn`s is to remove the vertical rules inserted with your column specification `|c|c|c|c|`. Finally, `\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}` raises the entire `\underbrace` up half a line.

Answer (score 13):

There is also `\upbracefill` (and `\downbracefill`) which uses `\leaders` to build an extending brace. For example, `\hbox to 5cm{\upbracefill}` would "fill" that five centimeter length with the brace.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c}
     p
   & q
   & p\lor{}q
   & p\land{}q \\
  \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  \noalign{\vspace{-3pt}}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{${\upbracefill}$} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scriptstyle\ell} \\
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used `$\upbracefill$` before for the brace cell, and I was wondering that what happened was that the array cells are in display math mode, so then, I suppose, the outer display math mode got discarded because `$` starts math mode (while already in math mode), and `\upbracefill` starts (and closes) *another* math mode, and finally the last `$` closes the math mode started by the first `$`. If that is the case, then I guess it was better before the edit.

Comment: `\omit` and `\multispan` are not very idiomatic latex the same could be made with `\multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{${\upbracefill}$} \\  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scriptstyle\ell} \\ ` This answer was referenced here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400513/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I understand, I’ll amend the answer. Btw can you tell how the original answer worked? It’s been puzzling me.

Comment: @morbusg but it's your answer:-) Which bit is puzzling?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your solution does not start/end at the vertical lines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and it contains more vertical space above the upbrace

Comment: @Ben `@{}c@{}` fixes the width and possibly easiest way to adjust the vertical position is `\noalign` (or the booktabs package has a command for adding inter-row space) `\noalign{\vspace{-3pt}}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{${\upbracefill}$} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\scriptstyle\ell} \\ `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in the original answer I had `$\upbracefill$` as the `array` cell content (note the math mode). Now, as the cells are already in math mode inside `array`, I don't quite understand how it was able to work, as `$$` starts a display math mode (illegal inside `\halign`?).

Comment: @morbusg that;same as i did although I added `{}` for safety. the math mode cell is `$...$`  and you added `$$...$$` so there are two empty math lists doing nothing (unless you set mathsurround) and ... is out of math mode. `$$` is an empty math  list not a start of display math in inner h mode (try `\mbox{$$ one two three $$}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh! Oh!! "`$$` is an empty math list in inner h mode" This was completely new to me, Thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is there a list of idiomatic latex commands which are from plain/core (as here \omit is non-idiomatic, but \noalign isn’t)?

Comment: `\noalign`  isn't either (as I say there is a booktabs alternative) but without a package there isn't an obvious alternative normally you could use `\\[-2pt]` but not after `\hline` a failing in the latex syntax.  but no list really: it's a judgment call whether using lower level things likely to break other macros. I only commented on the `\multispan` use as spanning cells is trickier  than `\noalign` and as a user had shown that it didn't really work with beamer, I felt it was probably easier to change this than change beamer or add some complicated workaround to make it all work together .

Comment: shorter version of the above: I break my own rules:-)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the usual overkill solution with `tikz`.

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.

### References:

- This is a tweaked version of [Overbrace in amsmath align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26810/4301).  A `\VerticalOffset` have been added to shift the brace to compensate for the `\hline`.
- The brace is adapted from [adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1568/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\BraceAmplitude}{0.5em}%  Can be tweaked if
\newcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{1.2ex}%  necessary.
\newcommand*{\HorizontalOffset}{0.8em}%  necessary.
\newcommand*{\InsertUnderBrace}[4][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=\BraceAmplitude},decorate, thick,draw=blue,text=black,#1]
        ($(#3)+(\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$) -- 
        ($(#2)+(-\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$)
        node [below=\VerticalOffset, midway] {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%


\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c}
   p
 & q
 & p\lor{}q
 & p\land{}q \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & \tikzmark{StartBrace}1 & 1\tikzmark{EndBrace} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]
\InsertUnderBrace[draw=red,text=blue]{StartBrace}{EndBrace}{Explanation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I couldn't make this work.  Yours is much prettier.

Comment: @RyanReich: Helps to have something to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) solution, this time using a `matrix of math nodes`. There is some trickery with `pic` to put the underbrace in the right place, but the end result is:

[image]

Of course, you can add colour and styling to your heart's content!
Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\newdimen\colL
\newdimen\colR

\tikzset{%
  pics/underbrace/.style args={#1,#2,#3,#4}{%
    % a pic for putting an underbrace under certain columns
    % #1 = left column
    % #2 = right column index
    % #3 = index of the row with the underbrace
    % #4 = label text
    code = {
       \pgfextractx\colL{\pgfpointanchor{M-#3-#1}{south west}}  % x-coords of columns
       \pgfextractx\colR{\pgfpointanchor{M-#3-#2}{south east}}
       % draw the delimiter with the correct width
       \node[rectangle, below delimiter={\}}, minimum width=\dimexpr\colR-\colL-1pt]
              at ($ (M-#3-#1)!0.5!(M-#3-#2)+(0,-0.1) $){};
       % the label
       \node at ($ (M-#3-#1.south)!0.5!(M-#3-#2.south) $)[below=2mm]{$\scriptstyle #4$};
       }
   },
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,
                  nodes={anchor=center,rectangle,
                         minimum width=9mm, minimum height=5mm,
                         inner sep=0mm
                  }
      ]{
          p & q & p\lor{}q & p\land{}q \\
          0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
          1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
          1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      };
      % vertical lines
      \foreach \c in {1,...,4} {
         \draw[thick](M-1-\c.north west)--(M-5-\c.south west);
      }
      % horizontal lines
      \foreach \r in {1,5} {
        \draw[thick](M-\r-1.south west)--(M-\r-4.south east);
      }
      % and, finally, the underbrace!
      \pic{underbrace={3,4,5,\ell}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```