# Using \multicolumn inside overlay

Tags: beamer, multicolumn, overlays

How can I use `\multicolumn` together with overlays?

`\multicolumn` fails if there is an overlay **before** it or if `\multicolumn` is used **inside** an overlay.

I actually want to do the last. `\only<2>{\multicolumn{2}{c}{three}\\}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|>{$}{c}<{$}}|}
\hline
a & b & c & d\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
%TODO following works
\multicolumn{2}{c}{one}\\
\only<2>{one\\}
%TODO following doesn't work
%\only<2>{two\\}
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{two}\\
%TODO following doesn't work
%\only<2>{\multicolumn{2}{c}{three}\\}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why would you want \multispan and not \multicolumn? \multispan comes from plain tex and was never intended to be used in tabular directly

Comment: I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62573/using-underbrace-with-table-columns/62577#62577) answer

Comment: don't believe everything you read on the internet:-) I left a comment on that answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your help so far, but also `\multicolumn` doesn't work inside an overlay

Comment: I'd expect `\only<2>{\\\multicolumn{.....}}` to work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\only<2>{\\[-\normalbaselineskip]\multicolumn{2}{c}{three}}` compiles without errors, but the vertical lines of the "jumped" line are overprinted by `three`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle do you know a nice command to go back to the rowstart, so I don't have to calculate it (see my answer)

Comment: you need of course to make sure each layer has the same numer of `\\ ` so remove the one at the end of the previous row.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle actually there should be a `\hline` after my previous row. I solved this problem (see comment on you answer)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you want something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|>{$}{c}<{$}}|}
\hline
aaa & b & c & d\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{th}
\only<1>{\\\multicolumn{2}{l}{}}
\only<2>{\\\multicolumn{2}{l}{th}}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Or the following, which makes the same output in this case.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|>{$}{c}<{$}}|}
\hline
aaa & b & c & d\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{th}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\only<2>{th}}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your second solution doesn't work nice, if you change it to something like `\multicolumn{2}{l}{\only<2>{th2}}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\only<3>{th3}}` by this there if an empty line (or one have to get the first parameter get calculated basing on `\only`s)

Comment: Your first solution is fine. Thanks. To achieve, what I actually want, just delete `\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{th}` and add `\hline` before the two `\multicolumn`s like `\\\hline\multicolumn`

Answer (score 1):

Right now I got:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlength{\widthoffirstcolumn}
\settowidth{\widthoffirstcolumn}{%
\begin{tabular}{>{$}{c}<{$}}% %here are not | on purpose (still not the exact indent)
aaa\\
1
\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|>{$}{c}<{$}}|}
\hline
aaa & b & c & d\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{th}\\ %only for testing the indent of next row
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\only<2>{&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\hspace{-\widthoffirstcolumn}th}\\}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` is for not getting vertical lines

The `\hspace{-\widthoffirstcolumn}` goes back the to start of the row

---

I'm not sure if this is a nice solution, but it works... (the rowstart isn't calculated exactly)