# How can I name multiple columns in a table?

Tags: tables, overbrace

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
     \caption{Types of Aggregation}
    \label{table:my_label1}

    \begin{tabular}{|c |c| c| c|}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{}{$\overbrace{\rule{12.5em}{0pt}}^{Spatial Aggregation}$}\\
    \hline

     Meters & $time_1$ & $time_2$ & $time_3$ \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline

     $SM_{1}$ & $R_{1,1}$ & $R_{1,2}$ & $R_{1,3}$\\
    \hline
     $SM_2$  & $R_{2,1}$ & $R_{2,2}$ & $R_{2,3}$\\
    \hline
     $SM_3$  & $R_{3,1}$ & $R_{3,2}$ & $R_{3,3}$\\ 
    \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I want to name the 2nd, 3rd and 4th column using `\overbrace`. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just a note: It's easier for others to help if the example code is a [complete but minimal LaTeX document](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of just a code excerpt.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Assuming you want something similar to your code, you could use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
 \caption{Types of Aggregation}
 \label{table:my_label1}
 \begin{tabular}{|c |c| c| c|}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& 
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\overbrace{\rule{9.5em}{0pt}}^{\text{Spatial
   Aggregation}}$}\\
    \hline
     Meters & $\text{time}_1$ & $\text{time}_2$ & $\text{time}_3$ \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline
     $SM_{1}$ & $R_{1,1}$ & $R_{1,2}$ & $R_{1,3}$\\
    \hline
     $SM_2$  & $R_{2,1}$ & $R_{2,2}$ & $R_{2,3}$\\
    \hline
     $SM_3$  & $R_{3,1}$ & $R_{3,2}$ & $R_{3,3}$\\ 
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\downbracefill`, similar to what is suggested in [Using `\underbrace` with table columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62573/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| *{4}{c |} }
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\small Spatial aggregation} \\[-.3\normalbaselineskip]
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\downbracefill} \\
  \hline
  Meters & $time_1$ & $time_2$ & $time_3$ \\
  \hline
  $SM_1$ & $R_{1,1}$ & $R_{1,2}$ & $R_{1,3}$  \\
  \hline
  $SM_2$ & $R_{2,1}$ & $R_{2,2}$ & $R_{2,3}$  \\
  \hline
  $SM_3$ & $R_{3,1}$ & $R_{3,2}$ & $R_{3,3}$  \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```