# Typesetting 144...4 with "n times" under the 4's is easy, but what about \sqrt{144...4}?

Tags: math-mode

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170557/856) on the math StackExchange, suppose you want to typeset the square root of the number 144...4, that is, 1 followed by *n* 4's. If you write `$\sqrt{1\underbrace{44\ldots4}_{n\ \text{times}}}$`, as in the current version of the question, you get a huge radical sign that reaches down to match the "*n* times" text below the number. Is there an elegant way to typeset this so that the radical sign looks like it would with `$\sqrt{144\ldots4}$`, but also keeping the underset text in the right place?

Comment: Related Questions: [Underbrace under nested square roots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338085/4301) and [How to ignore the underbrace{}{} in a square root?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176103/4301).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd recommend the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt{\smash[b]{1\! \underbrace{44\cdots4\,}_\text{$n$ times}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that it's syntactically cleaner to place `$n$ times` inside a `\text` macro. The `\smash[b]` command "hides" the stuff below the baseline from TeX, inducing it *not* to make the lower end of square-root symbol plunge down to far. The `\!` instruction removes the unnecessary whitespace otherwise inserted by the left-hand end of the underbrace, while `\,` serves to avoid a clash between the right-hand end of the underbrace and the final `4`. Finally, and I realize that some will disagree with me, I think it's better to use `\cdots` than `\ldots` in this case.

**Addendum**: This MWE was meant to produce an image of a single formula in which the "root" of the square-root symbol doesn't plunge down unnecessarily far. If this formula were part of some longer running text, a problem would immediately arise: the following line of text and math -- and, depending on the depth of the underbrace contents, even the line after that -- will run smack over the underbrace material. As @egreg notes in his comment and as @Werner shows in his answer, to keep this from happening the formula should be augmented to contain a `\vphantom` *outside* the square-root that has the exact same depth as the formula would have if `\smash` weren't being used. This may be done, e.g., as follows:

```
$\vphantom{\underbrace{4}_{n}} \sqrt{\smash[b]{1\! \underbrace{44\cdots4\,}_\text{$n$ times}}}$
```

Comment: Mico, how are you getting the nice graphic to upload?  Whenever I try to upload and crop the generated pdf, I get a tiny picture that scales into a pixelated mess.

Comment: @ScottH. - I crop the image file very tightly and then save it as a png file at 300 dpi.

Comment: In which program?

Comment: @ScottH.: Perhaps some of the links in [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764) might be helpful. I do a regular screen capture (in Windows, PrntScr), then paste in Paint, and crop the image to the desired size, then save as a PNG and upload.

Comment: @ScottH. -- I use Acrobat 9.5.

Comment: @ScottH. Alternatively, just use the `standalone` document class, a huge font size, and the `\Huge` modifier right at the beginning.  Then you don't have to process the result.

Comment: A `\vphantom{\underbrace{4}_{n}}` *outside* the argument of `\sqrt` is necessary to tell TeX what vertical space is occupied.

Comment: @egreg -- Thanks for this comment. I'll provide an addendum to make a note of this point.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \sqrt{144\ldots4\smash{\llap{$\underbrace{\phantom{44\ldots4}}_{\text{$n$ times}}$}}}
    \vphantom{1\underbrace{44\ldots4}_{\text{$n$ times}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

The "entire" number is typeset, followed by a `l`eft over`lap` that is `\smash`ed. The additional (almost duplicate) `\vphantom` is to ensure that the vertical height of the expression matches that of what is visible, otherwise the underbrace might stretch into text below it.

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\text`.

Answer (score 6):

The standard overkill TikZ solution using the infamous `\tikzmark` works great for situations such as this:

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.

### References:

- This is a tweaked version of the solution used in [Using \underbrace with table columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62576/4301), and [Overbrace in amsmath align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60046/4301).
- The brace is adapted from [adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1568/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

% Tweak these as necessary
\newcommand*{\BraceAmplitude}{0.4em}%
\newcommand*{\VerticalOffset}{0.4ex}%  
\newcommand*{\HorizontalOffset}{0.0em}% 
\newcommand*{\SquareBraceVOffset}{-0.4ex}% 

\newcommand*{\InsertUnderBrace}[4][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=\BraceAmplitude},decorate, thick,draw=blue,text=black,#1]
        ($(#3)+(\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$) -- 
        ($(#2)+(-\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset)$)
        node [below=\VerticalOffset, midway] {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\newcommand*{\InsertUnderSquareBrace}[4][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw [text=black,line width=0.7pt, #1]
            ($(#3)+(0,\VerticalOffset+\SquareBraceVOffset)$) -- 
            ($(#3)+(\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset+\SquareBraceVOffset)$) -- 
            ($(#2)+(-\HorizontalOffset,-\VerticalOffset+\SquareBraceVOffset)$)
            node [below, midway] {#4} --
            ($(#2)+(0,\VerticalOffset+\SquareBraceVOffset)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
\[
    \sqrt{1\tikzmark{StartBraceA}44\cdots4\tikzmark{EndBraceA}\,}
    \quad
    \sqrt{1\tikzmark{StartBraceB}44\cdots4\tikzmark{EndBraceB}\,}
\]

\InsertUnderBrace[draw=red,text=blue]{StartBraceA}{EndBraceA}{$n$ times}

\InsertUnderSquareBrace[draw=red,text=blue]{StartBraceB}{EndBraceB}{$n$ times}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The command `\raisebox` has two optional argument: the height and depth of the resulting box.  You want your expression with underbrace to have zero depth and the natural height, so this works:

```
$\sqrt{1
\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{$\underbrace{44\ldots4}_{n\ \text{times}}$}}$
```

[image]

The `\smash` command in the Scott H.'s answer does almost the same.

Answer (score 5):

The answers are great but this time I couldn't stop myself to write up an answer though there are 4 answers already. The detail I'm kind of obsessed is the underbraces and their fat appearance when the argument is short. Thanks to the [`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools) package this issue is solved to a great extent and moreover you can also use less intrusive `\underbracket`. Here are two examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\sqrt{\smash[b]{1\kern-2pt\underbracket[0.5pt][1pt]{4\cdots 44}_\text{$n$ many}}}\]

\[\sqrt{\smash[b]{1\kern-2pt\underbrace{4\cdots 44}_\text{$n$ many}}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the brace arms are smoothly rendered instead of a rather crude concatenation.

Comment: `n many` sounds odd.  I otherwise agree that a bracket looks nicer than a brace here.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Ehm, that's probably my bad English interfering.

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt{\smash{1\underbrace{44\ldots4}_{n\ \text{times}}}\vphantom{1}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep. And it looks like someone has used `\smash` on the post that inspired this question too.

Comment: A good solution.  However, you do not need `\vphantom`:  `$\sqrt{1\smash{\underbrace{44\ldots4}_{n\ \text{times}}}}$`

Comment: Ahh, good point.  It didn't occur to me to leave the one outside!