# Underbrace under nested square roots

Tags: formatting, equations, underbrace

I am trying to put an underbrace underneath a the innermost of multiple square root signs. Unfortunately, I can't get the brace to line up underneath the entire line. Here's the relevant code and a picture of the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}f(f(f(x))) &= f\left(f\left(\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\right)\right) \\
&= \sqrt{\sqrt{\underbrace{\sqrt{1+0}}_{\text{Because $f(x)$ is continuous}}}}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

It should be pretty clear what I'm talking about from the picture.

It would also be cool if I could get the two outermost square root signs to be the same, but it's not a huge deal. The underbrace is the main issue here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related Questions: [Typesetting 144…4 with “n times” under the 4's is easy, but what about \sqrt{144…4}?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63250/4301) and [How to ignore the underbrace{}{} in a square root?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176103/4301)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three suggestions:

- Encase the text below the underbrace in a `\mathclap` directive so that its width doesn't affect the widths of the outermost and middle square-root symbols,
- Use a `\smash[b]{...}` directive to ensure that the outer surds have the same (zero) depth, and
- Insert a `\\` directive at the end of the second line to ensure enough whitespace below the equation. (The `\smash` directive has "hidden" the underbrace material from TeX's ordinary spacing calculations.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}f(f(f(x))) 
&= f\Bigl(f\bigl(\,\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\bigr)\Bigr) \\
&= \sqrt{\sqrt{\smash[b]{\underbrace{\sqrt{1+0}}_{%
   \mathclap{\text{because $f(x)$ is continuous}}}}}}\\ % <-- note the "\\"
\end{align*}
Some text following this two-line displayed equation.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of `\smash`ing the and `\vphantom` to ensure a proper vertical spacing and `\mathclap` to remove the horizontal intrusion of the under-script.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{x \to 0} f(f(f(x))) &= f\bigl( f\bigl( \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \bigr)\bigr) \\
                            &= \sqrt{\sqrt{\underbrace{\sqrt{1+0}}_{\text{Because $f(x)$ is continuous}}}} \\
                            &= \sqrt{\sqrt{
                                 \vphantom{\sqrt{1}}
                                 \smash{\underbrace{\sqrt{1+0}}_{\mathclap{\text{Because $f(x)$ is continuous}}}}
                               }}
                               \vphantom{\underbrace{\sqrt{1}}_{\text{Because $f(x)$ is continuous}}}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

An additional `\vphantom` at the end ensures the appropriate vertical spacing after the `align` is maintained if content follows it.