# how to write this nested expression

Tags: nesting

How to write this mathematical expression in Latex
[image]

I have no idea ..please help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you know about `\underbrace`?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Typesetting 144...4 with "n times" under the 4's is easy, but what about `\sqrt{144...4}`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63250/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it (load `amsmath`):

```
\[\underbrace{111\dots 111}_{100 \text{ times}} \]
```