# How should I typeset repeated multiplication?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I need to expand an exponent and I want to typeset it as such:

```
                 n times
A^k = A * A * A * ... * A * A
```

Is there a way to do this in LaTeX? Should I be doing something else altogether? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps somethine like [Typesetting 144…4 with “n times” under the 4's is easy, but what about \sqrt{144…4}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63250/typesetting-144-4-with-n-times-under-the-4s-is-easy-but-what-about-sqrt1/63314#63314).

Comment: You could use `\prod_{i=1}^k A` ;-)

Comment: @JohnKormylo you're absolutely right, but I wanted it fully written out so I could show that parts of the product telescoped. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
    A^k \coloneqq \overbrace{A\times A\times \cdots \times A}^{k-\text{times}}
\]

\end{document}
```