# How can I draw annotated braces over and under math expressions?

Tags: math-mode, braces

What LaTeX markup would one have to write to produce a result similar to the image below?

[image]

Please excuse my Paint-and-mouse drawing skills. :-)

Comment: Well, depending on how fancy you want to get there is always a `\tikzmark` solution... :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill Do you have an example of something fancy? :-)

Comment: Well, have a look at [Curly brace to insert something into an equation? Like an inverted underbrace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47017/curly-brace-to-insert-something-into-an-equation-like-an-inverted-underbrace/47032#47032), or [Asymmetric overbrace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68526/asymmetric-overbrace/68537#68537), or [Overbrace in amsmath align environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26729/overbrace-in-amsmath-align-environment/60046#60046). Only useful, if you perhaps want to add color, change the arrow tips, etc...

Comment: Also have a look at the [`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools) package for fixing the spacing of the braces and introducing brackets together with many other fixes to amsmath package. Section 3.3.2 is the part I've mentioned.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\text` can help to obtain the correct size of superscript/subscript fonts in math mode, while the bracing it possible using the traditional `\overbrace`/`\underbrace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
$\overbrace{a\rightarrow\underbrace{(b\rightarrow c)}_{\text{bar}}}^{\text{foo}}$
\end{document}
```

For other symbols (like arrows), see the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive).

Comment: Ok that was a fast and (so far) perfect answer. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 12):

While Werner's solution is compact and precise, this one shows other possibilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[
  \overset{\text{foo}}{\overbrace{a\rightarrow \underset{\text{bar}}{\underbrace{(b \rightarrow c)}}}}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would go Werner's way if I have to do this `:-)`. (This answer is for having some fun).