# Nonstandard (non?)nesting of over- and under-braces

Tags: nesting

```
\overbrace{ABCDEFG = HIJKL} = PQRSTUV
ABCDEFG = \underbrace{HIJKL = PQRSTUV}
```

LaTeX can handle either of the lines above.  How can I get *both* the overbrace and the underbrace, when they overlap like that?

Comment: Related: [How can I draw annotated braces over and under math expressions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79365/5764); [How to put a big bracket under different parts of a equation so that I could write e.g. a text specific to that part in the equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44834/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package oubraces should solve your problem!

Check here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oubraces?lang=en

Once you load the package, the command works like this:

```
\overunderbraces{upper braces}{main formula}{lower braces}
```

which needs you to split your equation into multiple columns using &, and the braces command is

```
\br{n}{label}
```

where n is the number of columns to span and the label braces can be left blank.

So for your example, you'd have

```
\[
\overunderbraces{&\br{2}{}&}{&ABCDEFG= & HIJKL &=PQRSTUV}{&&\br{2}{}}
\]
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use some trickery. The following uses [How to put a big bracket under different parts of a equation so that I could write e.g. a text specific to that part in the equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44838/5764) as a guide:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}% Just for this example
  \begin{array}{c}
    \overbrace{ABCDEFG = HIJKL} = PQRSTUV \\
    ABCDEFG = \underbrace{HIJKL = PQRSTUV} \\
    \mathrlap{\overbrace{\phantom{ABCDEFG = HIJKL}}}
    ABCDEFG =
    \underbrace{HIJKL = PQRSTUV}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```