# Nonstandard nesting of left and right vertical braces

Tags: arrays, braces

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249270/nonstandard-nonnesting-of-over-and-under-braces#) I asked about non-standard nesting of over- and underbraces. Now I have occasion to do the same thing with \left{ and \right} in an array, thus

```
\begin{array}{l}

A  \\  B  \\  C  \\  D  \\  E

\end{array}
```

A right brace to the right of this array would encompass A, B, and C, and a left brace to its left would encompass C, D, and E, so the braces overlap.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

Here I've set the left brace in a left column, the "data" in the middle column and the right brace in the right column. `\mathstrut`s are used in place of content, but one could consider using `\vphantom` if the content is not regularly spaced:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{array}{ *{3}{c} }
    \begin{array}{ c }
      \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\
      \left\{\begin{array}{ c } \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \end{array}\right.
    \end{array} &
    \begin{array}{ c}
      One \\ Two \\ Three \\ Four \\ Five
    \end{array}
    \begin{array}{ c }
      \left.\begin{array}{c}
        \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
      \end{array}\right\} \\
      \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
    \end{array}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `pstricks` and another with the `dcases` and `drcases` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %
\usepackage{pstricks-add, auto-pst-pdf}%
\psset{linejoin=1, braceWidth=1pt, braceWidthInner=2pt, braceWidthOuter=2.5pt}
 \begin{document}

\[ \begin{pspicture} \begin{matrix}
    A \pnode[1pt, 1.8ex]{A}\\ %
    B\\ %
   \pnode[-1pt, 1.8ex]{C1} C \pnode[1pt, -0.2ex]{C}\\%
    D\\ %
   \pnode[-1pt, -0.3ex]{E} E \\ %
  \end{matrix}
    \psbrace(C)(A){}
    \psbrace(C1)(E){}
    \end{pspicture}
\]
    \vspace{-4ex}
\begin{align*}
  & \begin{drcases}
    A\\ %
    B\\ %
    C\\%
  \end{drcases}\\[-1.06\baselineskip]
  & \hspace{-0.76em}\begin{dcases}
    \phantom{C}\\%
    D \\%
    E \\%
    \end{dcases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]