# How to form braces or brackets used in math formulas around nodes in a TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, braces, brackets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text)

I'm trying to create a brace or bracket around two or more nodes within a TikZ picture. Since there are more elements in the picture which are not to be encompassed by the bracket or brace, I can't use the "insert the picture into LaTeX math mode" approach.

[image: How do I get that bracket there in TikZ?]

Here's the example code, for easy copy-pasting:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle, fill=black, minimum size=1cm}]
  \node [box] (a) {};
  \node [box, below=of a] (b) {};
  \node [box, below=of b] (c) {};
  \node [box, below=of c] (d) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is only _after_ I've asked a question that I stumble upon the answer, but never when having looked around for half an hour _before_ asking? Anyway, I found how to do this in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1568#1568 Don't know if this should be closed or I should put it as answer...

Comment: Often how it goes.  I think that for this one, I'd go for "close as duplicate".

Comment: (Closing as duplicate makes it easier for later searchers to find the right question.)

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree that it's an *exact* duplicate, as the referenced question doesn't involve Tikz...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: Well, at least whoever is looking for exactly this will find it if he or she reads the comments.