# Box around single element in list

Tags: lists, boxes

Is there any way in latex to create a simple box around one item in a list? 
I tried both `\framebox`, and `\fbox`, none of them worked

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*),ref=\Alph*]
{\color{red}\item null.} 
\item lik vektdifferansen $GT - GK$.
\item lik vektsummen $GT + GK$.
\item lik vekten av $K$.
\end{enumerate}
```

Works, but

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*),ref=\Alph*]

{\color{red}  \fbox{ \item null.} } 

\item lik vektdifferansen $GT - GK$.
\item lik vektsummen $GT + GK$.
\item lik vekten av $K$.
\end{enumerate}
```

Does not. So yeah, any way to box a single entry in a list?

Comment: Presumably `\item\fbox{null.}` is not acceptable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a way of boxing the text *and* label. It depends on explicitly calling the label. It might also need some tweaking for spacing.

It relies on [Andrew Stacey's super smart `\tikzmark` trick.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\tikzmark{bl}\textbullet] Something\tikzmark{br}
\item Something not boxed
\item Also not boxed.
\end{itemize}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[red]
  ($(bl)+(-0.2em,0.9em)$) rectangle
  ($(br)+(0.2em,-0.3em)$);}
\end{document}
```

[image: boxing items]

I am fully aware that this is overkill. [But that is a good thing!](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/overkill-is-a-good-thing/)

Comment: I expect this could be partially automated with a wrapper for `\item` but I don't have time to experiment right now…

Answer (score 7):

You can locally redefine `\labelenumi`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item.
  {\renewcommand\labelenumi{\fbox{\theenumi}}
  \item Second boxed item.}
  \item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item.
  {\renewcommand\labelenumi{\colorbox{red}{\theenumi}}
  \item Second boxed and colored item.}
  \item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This only boxes the label though, not the item.

Comment: @wh1t3 yes. I thought that that was the intention of the OP.