# Box around some of the elements in an enumerate list

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate

I need to put a box around the label of an enumerate list. This is solved in 
[Colored box around enumerate labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127602/colored-box-around-enumerate-labels) but, my problem is that I need to do that just in some of the elements marked, for example using a command different from `\item` (but the numbering should be continuous).

Comment: Does this achieve what you're after? [Box around single element in list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33446) (You can of course package it in a more convenient macro too.)

Comment: @Paul Gessler Looks very promossing. Maybe someone can mark the question as duplicate.