# Arrow between parts of equation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols

I want to make an arrow under an equation pointing from one part of the equation to another. A bit like an underbrace, but with an arrow. How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want the arrow to point to specific parts of the equation or not.

Comment: Should the arrow be straight or curved?

Answer (score 33):

Using `TikZ`, you can place a node for the starting point of the arrow and another one for the ending point, and then join the nodes using the kind of arrow that you desire; a little example, using a curved red arrow and some code to place the nodes borrowed from [this answer by Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a\tikzmark{a}x^2 + bx + c = 5\tikzmark{b}x^2 + bx + c.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,out=315,in=225,distance=0.4cm]
    \draw[->,red,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt] (a.center) to (b.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this be improved to enable similar arrows that appear on the top as well?

Comment: Worth noting that the tikzmark command is now available as part of the tikzmark tikz library. The exact replacement for the command here is `\tikzmarknode`

Answer (score 8):

Try this one:

`\underrightarrow{y = ax^2 + bx + c}`

It will look like this:

[image: formula]

Answer (score 5):

The document [mathmode](http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode) has the sections *Over- and underbrackets* and *Extensible arrows*

If you want to define your own style please have a look into the the linked document. An example of the document is shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\mapstofill@{%
\arrowfill@{\mapstochar\relbar}\relbar\rightarrow}
\newcommand*\xmapsto[2][]{%
\ext@arrow0099\mapstofill@{#1}{\displaystyle#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$\underrightarrow{y = ax^2 + bx + c}$


$\xmapsto{y = ax^2 + bx + c}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also put the equation inside the tikzpicture environment, and then simply draw the line using controls. Here is a MWE. You can adjust the length of the line as you find suitable.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
$\begin{aligned}
\left<\theta_{\mathrm{space}}^2\right> = \left<\theta_y^2\right> + \left<\theta_x^2\right> = 2 \left<\theta_{\mathrm{plane}}^2\right> = \theta_{\mathrm{plane}}^2
\draw[<->] (-4.43,-0.2)  .. controls (-4.065,-0.7) .. (-3.7,-0.2);
\node[] at (-4.065,-0.45) {\small =};
\end{aligned}$
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add an screenshot of your result to your answer ...