# How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, diagrams, arrows, technical-drawing

There is a part of my paper where I use the distributive property and it might not be clear to the reader to see the operation result (I'm using in proposional logic for a proof). The logic equation (part of) is:

```
$$ (l_{1}) \vee \big( (p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (p \vee \neg q) \wedge (\neg p \vee \neg q)\big) $$
$$ (l_{1} \vee p \vee q) \wedge (l_{1} \vee \neg p \vee q) \wedge (l_{1} \vee p \vee \neg q) \wedge (l_{1} \vee \neg p \vee \neg q) $$
```

So I was wondering if there is a way to represent this operation like a 'shower' (see another example in pic [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMniS.jpg)). Maybe there is some hidden magic mathmode command or pkg for this. At last we can also rely on tikz.

[image: Distributive Property]

Comment: As this has returned to the front page, I'll just take the opportunity to note that `\tikzmark`, which is used in a couple of answers, is now available in its own TikZ library: `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following uses [`pst-node`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) from the [`pstricks` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks). So, you need to compile it with either `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`, or `xelatex`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \psDefBoxNodes{n1}{(l_{1})} \vee \big( 
      \psDefBoxNodes{n2}{(p \vee q)} \wedge 
      \psDefBoxNodes{n3}{(\neg p \vee q)} \wedge 
      \psDefBoxNodes{n4}{(p \vee \neg q)} \wedge 
      \psDefBoxNodes{n5}{(\neg p \vee \neg q)}\big) \\
    (l_{1} \vee p \vee q) \wedge (l_{1} \vee \neg p \vee q) \wedge (l_{1} \vee p \vee \neg q) \wedge (l_{1} \vee \neg p \vee \neg q)
  \end{array}
\]
\psset{nodesep=3pt,arcangle=15}
\ncarc{->}{n1:tC}{n2:tC}
\ncarc{->}{n1:tC}{n3:tC}
\ncarc{->}{n1:tC}{n4:tC}
\ncarc{->}{n1:tC}{n5:tC}
\end{document}
```

`\psDefBoxNodes{<node>}{<stuff>}` declares a special node `<node>` for `<stuff>`. Subsequently one can refer to the bounding box location of the node using character combinations. In the above example, `<node>:tC` refers to the `t`op `C`enter of `<node>`.

Comment: @Werner: If you put `arrows = ->` inside `\psset` you can avoid all the `{->}`s.

Answer (score 43):

### Adapted Solution:

Here is a version of the *Basic Solution* below adapted to your specific case:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[4]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,-latex,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=70,in=130]
    \draw[distance=0.45cm,#1] (a.north) to (b.north);
    \draw[distance=0.65cm,#2] (a.north) to (c.north);
    \draw[distance=0.9cm, #3] (a.north) to (d.north);
    \draw[distance=1.1cm, #4] (a.north) to (e.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
(\tikzmark{a}l_{1}) \vee \big( (p \vee\tikzmark{b} q) \wedge (\neg p \vee\tikzmark{c} q) \wedge (p \vee\tikzmark{d} \neg q) \wedge (\neg p \vee\tikzmark{e} \neg q)\big) \DrawBox{red}{blue}{green}{orange}\\
(l_{1} \vee p \vee q) \wedge (l_{1} \vee \neg p \vee q) \wedge (l_{1} \vee p \vee \neg q) \wedge (l_{1} \vee \neg p \vee \neg q)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

---

### Notes:

- As with most `\tikzmark`s, this does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

---

### Basic Solution:

You can use `tikz` and the `\tikzmark` as defined in [Arrow between parts of equation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/arrow-between-parts-of-equation-in-latex)).  Each endpoint of an arc is identified by `\tikzmark`, and the `\DrawBox` macro draws the arc between each of the nodes.  The arc angle going out are adjusted by `out=`, and the incoming angle of the endpoint is specified by `in=`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}


\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=70,in=130,distance=0.5cm,#1] (MarkA.north) to (MarkC.north);
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=50,in=140,distance=0.3cm,#2] (MarkA.north) to (MarkB.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tikzmark{MarkA}5 (x\tikzmark{MarkB} + 6\tikzmark{MarkC})\DrawBox{red}{blue}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @FaheemMitha: There was a change in the `standalone` package. Chane to `\documentclass{article}`. Fixing solution now...

Comment: The basic version (bottom of post) does not work for me. I get `ERROR: LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.`

Comment: Funny, from emacs it does not work. The command it uses is `pdflatex -shell-escape  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" peter.tex` and with the command the arrows are wrong. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you run it twice? Opps., looks like I forgot my usual "Notes" section. Will update...

Comment: @PeterGrill: Auctex (I assume) decides whether it should be run again. In this case, it doesn't think it needs to be. I see that if I run it twice, it does give the correct picture.

Comment: Could you provide a basic example how to do (a+b)(c+d) multiplication using tikz?

Comment: @Eugene: Just add a `\tikzmark` _before_ the `a` term, and then `\draw`the lines from this additional mark to the other terms. If you are still have trouble, let me know as in the second example above. Also see [Better solution to display the Distributive Property](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60763/better-solution-to-display-the-distributive-property/60770#60770).

Comment: +1 for this nice answer! I am currently on a promotion tour in which I advertize the new [tikzmark](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark) version, with which your answer can be made arguably even simpler: the command `\tikzmarknode` allows you to wrap for instance the `5` in a node, such that you don't have to use all the `shorten` keys (I think).

Answer (score 26):

Just to add something to the great answers already here: it's sometimes useful to have squared arrows instead of curved arrows.  Here's an example of how you can do that.  The same style could be applied to any of the other solutions here (with some minor tweaking of the anchors.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\tikzset{square arrow/.style={to path={-- ++(0,-.25) -| (\tikztotarget)}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a\tikzmark{a}x^2 + bx + c = 5\tikzmark{b}x^2 + bx + c.
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
   {\draw[->,square arrow] (a.south) to (b.south);}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Response to comments

If you want to add a label text to the line you can do the following.  A big thanks to [Kpym](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9335/kpym) for improving this code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\tikzset{square arrow/.style={
    to path={-- ++(0,-.25)  -| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes},below,pos=.25}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a\tikzmark{a}x^2 + bx + c = 5\tikzmark{b}x^2 + bx + c.
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
   {\path[draw,->,square arrow] (a.south) to node{x} (b.south) ;
    }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: How can I put text midway of the line drawn?

Comment: I have the same question @azetina has. Using this method plus the `cancel` package would make really beautiful results.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández I've added way to add text to the line.

Comment: @azetina A bit late, but I've added a way to add text to the line. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alan! It won't work with `cancel` in the way I had in mind, but this alone will do magnificently!

Comment: @AlfredoHernández What did you have in mind with `cancel`?

Comment: @AlanMunn My idea was to have some `tikzmark`s inside a `cancel` group.

Comment: @AlanMunn It is probably better to add `\tikztonodes` in your macro, for example like this `square arrow/.style={to path={-- ++(0,-.25) -| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes},below,pos=.25`, and then to use it like this `(a.south) to node{X} (b.south)`.

Comment: @Kpym Thank you! I thought that `\tikztonodes` was what I should have been doing, and tried using it but I never managed to get the placement correct which is why I used the version I did. This makes the solution much better.

Comment: @AlanMunn you are welcome. I don't know exactly why the position is displaced : 0 is at the first corner and .5 is on the second one. Every time we use `-|` .5 is in the corner, I think.

Comment: How would you center the arrow tip and base to the center of the marked targets?

Comment: This solution does not work if the arrow has targets that are underlined

Answer (score 22):

Here's something that might be slightly more comfortable to use if you need this regularly.

I've defined three new commands, `\source`, `\target` and `\drawarrows`. In your equation, replace the source term with `\source{<source term>}`, and each of the `<target terms>` with `\target{<target term>}`. After your equation, issue `\drawarrows`, and the arrows will be drawn. The solution uses TikZ `overlay`, which means you have to compile the document twice to get the placement right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\source[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline,inner sep=0pt] {%
        \node [name=source,anchor=base]{$#1$};
    }%
    \setcounter{target}{0}
}

\newcounter{target}
\newcommand\target[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline,inner sep=0pt] {%
        \node [name=target-\thetarget,anchor=base]{$#1$};
    }%
    \stepcounter{target}%
}

\newcommand\drawarrows{
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay, bend left=20, -latex] {
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \n using int(\i-1)] in {1,...,\thetarget} {
            \draw (source.north) to (target-\n.north);
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}
$\source{(l_{1})}\vee \big( \target{(p \vee q)} \wedge \target{(\neg p \vee q)} \wedge \target{(p \vee \neg q)} \wedge \target{(\neg p \vee \neg q)}\big)$
\drawarrows
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake: I was just about to post that you should reset the counter at the end of `\drawarrows` so that if there is more than one use of this it still works, but somehow it appears as if that is not necessary. Am curious as to why? Let me know if I missed something obvious, of if it more involved I should probably most a new question.

Comment: @PeterGrill: The counter is reset at the end of `\source`. Hm, I wonder which place (end of `\source` or end of `\drawarrows`) makes more sense.

Comment: Ok, I guess my logic was doing to reset it at the end of `\drawarrows`, but I can't think of any downside of initializing at the start.