# How can I draw an arrow from one text element to another?

Tags: arrows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr)

Suppose I have the following text:

`{A, B, C, D, E}`

Now I would like to draw an arrow like `\lcirclearrowdown` from B to D. So this arrow should go over C. How can I do that?

Comment: Do any of the answers in [How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35717/5764) help?

Comment: I took a look at it and it seems to be what I was searching for. But I always get "! Undefined control sequence. [line-nr] \psDefBoxNodes". I get it with `$ latex latexsheet.tex` and `pdflatex latexsheet.tex -output-format=pdf`.

Comment: You need to compile with `latex latexsheet.tex`, `dvips latexsheet.dvi -o latexsheet.ps`, and finally `ps2pdf latexsheet.ps`. Alternatively, use `xelatex latexsheet.tex` for a direct compile to PDF. You *cannot* directly use `pdflatex latexsheet.tex` as-is.

Comment: If you use the `tikz` based solutions of PeterGrill or Jake, you just need to run `pdflatex` twice on your file

Comment: @cmhughes: Thanks, this works. Do you know why it works the second time?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've used it for the following post (LaTeX included): http://martin-thoma.com/minimierung-eines-automaten-mittels-aquivalenzklassenkonstruktion

Comment: Glad it works, and the post looks great! It takes a second time as it reads from the `.aux` file. If your question was answered by the other post, please indicate so that it can be flagged for moderator attention (they might like to close it as a duplicate)