# Inserting an image properly in a table

Tags: tables, graphics, arrows

I'd like to insert those lines that from "Foo" point to the four different rows in the table.

> [image]

I've tries inserting an image but it doesn't come out right (*please ignore the bad quality of the lines and the table not resembling the one above*):

> [image]

Here's the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}

    \begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c }

        & & A & B & C & D \\ \cline {2-6}
    \multirow{4}{*}{Foo \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{IMAGE HERE}}    & 1 & foo A1 & foo B1 & foo C1 & foo D1 \\
                            & 2 & foo A2 & foo B2 & foo C2 & foo D2 \\
                            & 3 & foo A3 & foo B3 & foo C3 & foo D3 \\
                            & 4 & foo A4 & foo B4 & foo C4 & foo D4 \\

    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Obviously, if you know of a "Tex-native" way to do this without using images, which quality will inevitably go poor when inserted, that would be a perfect solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Similar to the solution I provided in [How to draw arrows between parts of an equation to show the Math Distributive Property (Multiplication)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr/35719#35719), you can use `\tikzmark` as defined in [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).  Each endpoint of the line is identified by `\tikzmark`, and the `\DrawLines` macro draws the line between each of the nodes.

[image]

You can adjust the `shorten <=<size>` parameter to start the lines a little later which achieves a nice effect.  Here is the result with `shorten <=7pt`:

[image]

Curved lines can also be obtained by specifying `in=<angle>` and `out=<angle>` options. For example using `\DrawLinesCurved` instead of `DrawLines` you get:

[image]

### Notes:

- This requires two runs. Once to determine the begin and end point of the lines, and the second to draw them.
- The colors of the 4 lines are passed as parameters to `\DrawLines`.
- I used the `-latex` arrows here, but if arrows are not desired this option can be removed.
- I used `\raisebox` to adjust the position of the text (as requested in the comments).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand{\DrawLinesCurved}[4]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,-latex,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt, thick]
    \draw[out=80,  in=180, #1] (a.north) to (b.north west);
    \draw[out=40,  in=180, #2] (a.north) to (c.north west);
    \draw[out=320, in=180, #3] (a.north) to (d.north west);
    \draw[out=275, in=180, #4] (a.north) to (e.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\DrawLines}[4]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,-latex,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt, thick]
    \draw[#1] (a.north) to (b.north west);
    \draw[#2] (a.north) to (c.north west);
    \draw[#3] (a.north) to (d.north west);
    \draw[#4] (a.north) to (e.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\raisebox{-12pt}{Foo\tikzmark{a}}\hspace*{1.0cm}
\begin{tabular}[c]{ c c c c c c }
    & A & B & C & D \\ \cline {2-6}
    \tikzmark{b}1 & foo A1 & foo B1 & foo C1 & foo D1 \\
    \tikzmark{c}2 & foo A2 & foo B2 & foo C2 & foo D2 \\
    \tikzmark{d}3 & foo A3 & foo B3 & foo C3 & foo D3 \\
    \tikzmark{e}4 & foo A4 & foo B4 & foo C4 & foo D4 \\
\end{tabular}
\DrawLines{red}{blue}{green}{orange}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Just one thing: is it possible to make it so that "Foo" stays in the middle (when using multirow) so that the arrows come out symmetrical? :D It's just a "visual thing", as I think your answer pretty much does what I need. :D

Comment: @Alenanno: I placed the text `Foo` is outside of the table.  The pacement of `Foo` has nothing to do with this solution. You can move it as desired and the arrows will adjust with respect to where it is placed.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it and let you know. Another thing, is the color of the arrows editable? By the way, I +1'ed your answer. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: The color of the arrows is specified in the call to `\DrawLines`.  I also updated the solution to show how to move the location of the `\Foo` text.

Comment: Last thing and then I'll stop nagging you :D Can I choose to use lines instead of arrows?

Comment: @Alenanno: The arrow type is specified by `-latex`. You can just remove that option if you want just a line.

Comment: I forgot to say: thanks again for the quick and complete answer! :)

Comment: Peter, I have a problem. How do you determine the position of that "Foo"? I mean, when you wrote `\raisebox{-12pt}{Foo\tikzmark{a}}\hspace*{1.0cm}`, was it by tries? Or you can determine that? For example: If we multiply that table by 6 times (always a single tabular environment), how do you know where to "locate" the first Foo, then the second one, the third one and so on?

Comment: I think that would depend on exactly what `Foo` is. I just moved it until it looked liked it was centered as that was not the main thrust of this problem. Since it is unrelated to the drawing of the lines, it seems to me that you should post a separate question with more details on how you want to determine the location.  You can reference this question in your new question if it is relevant.

Comment: Oh sure. I didn't mean to overcome the SE rules! :D I thought it was something simple enough to be explained in a comment, but if you suggest me to ask another question, I suppose it isn't. :P

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,calc,pict2e}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\setlength\unitlength{\baselineskip + \extrarowheight}

    \begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c }

        & & A & B & C & D \\ \cline {2-6}
    \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{picture}(1,1)
\put(.5,.5){\makebox(0,0)[r]{foo }}
\put(.5,.5){\vector(2,3){1}}
\put(.5,.5){\vector(2,1){1}}
\put(.5,.5){\vector(2,-1){1}}
\put(.5,.5){\vector(2,-3){1}}
\end{picture}}    & 1 & foo A1 & foo B1 & foo C1 & foo D1 \\
                            & 2 & foo A2 & foo B2 & foo C2 & foo D2 \\
                            & 3 & foo A3 & foo B3 & foo C3 & foo D3 \\
                            & 4 & foo A4 & foo B4 & foo C4 & foo D4 \\

    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: May I suggest a `\usepackage{pict2e}`?

Comment: I guess so, I forgot that package actually worked these days, for so many years it just printed a message saying it didn't exist:-) added

Answer (score 4):

Just to complement Peter's nice answer, I have used the `matrix` library. This might be of use since you have already typed in the tabular format so I just copied and pasted it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes] (footable) {
   &A & B & C & D \\
1 & foo A1 & foo B1 & foo C1 & foo D1 \\
2 & foo A2 & foo B2 & foo C2 & foo D2 \\
3 & foo A3 & foo B3 & foo C3 & foo D3 \\
4 & foo A4 & foo B4 & foo C4 & foo D4 \\
};
\draw (footable-2-1.north west) -- (footable-2-5.north east);
\node (Foo) at ([xshift=-1cm]$(footable-3-1.west)!0.5!(footable-4-1.west)$) {Foo};
\foreach \x in {2,...,5}{
\draw (Foo) -- (footable-\x-1);%replace (Foo) with (Foo.east) to focus the arrow origins
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So, basically `matrix` library allows us to type in the tabular data. Then we put a node of which coordinates are calculated by obtaining the middle point of 3rd and 4th rows and shifting it by `-1cm` on the horizontal axis via `calc` library. Then a `foreach` argument draws the lines.

Comment: Thank you! I have accepted Peter's answer, but I upvoted yours too because it's interesting as well! :)